# Анимация рисования линий головы льва при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, css-animation

У меня есть анимированное SVG  рисования линий головы льва, взято [отсюда](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1253)

Анимация реализуется с помощью изменения атрибута `path` `stroke-dashoffset="2000"` от максимального значения до ноля.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 
  width="200" height="200" viewBox="-30 85 600 600">
 
 
  <g  transform="scale(0.85) "> 
            
       <path class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke ="black" stroke-dasharray= "2000" stroke-dashoffset="2000" d="m272.2 113.6c-0.3 0-0.6 0-0.9 0.1-0.7 0.1 2.2 2.5 10.9 11.2 9.8 9.7 18.2 19.1 23 25.5 5.9 8.1 12.3 18.6 16.4 29.1 0.8 1.6 3.6 11.9 4.6 16.9 0.5 2.8 1 5.4 1.2 5.8 0.8 2.5 3.9-8.4 4.8-13 1.2-5.6 1.2-11.4 1-17.1-0.2-5.8-0.5-11.8-2.2-17.4-1.4-4.8-3.6-9.4-6.7-13.3-6.6-8.2-15.1-15.1-24.4-20.1-6.4-3.5-13.8-4.9-20.9-6.5-2.2-0.5-4.8-1.3-6.9-1.2zm194.7 0c-2.1 0-4.7 0.7-6.9 1.2-7.1 1.6-14.5 3.1-20.9 6.5-9.3 5-17.8 11.8-24.4 20.1-3.1 3.9-5.3 8.6-6.7 13.3-1.7 5.6-2 11.5-2.2 17.4-0.2 5.7-0.1 11.5 1 17.1 1 4.5 4 15.4 4.8 13 0.1-0.3 0.6-2.9 1.2-5.8 0.9-5 3.7-15.3 4.6-16.9 4.2-10.5 10.5-21 16.5-29.1 4.8-6.5 13.2-15.8 23-25.5 8.7-8.7 11.6-11.1 10.9-11.2-0.3 0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.1zm-97.3 24.5c-0.8-0.1-1.4 5.7-2 8.5-0.9 4.3-1.3 8.7-2.4 12.9-1.8 6.9-4.3 13.7-7.1 20.3-2.4 5.7-6.4 13.4-8.3 16.5-5.5 8.8-9 13.7-13.9 19.6-6.1 7.3-7.4 8.8-13 14.4-10.8 10.8-19.3 15.7-30 22.1-7.3 4.4-15.3 7.6-23.1 11-17.5 7.6-36.3 14.2-55.9 20.5-12.8 4.3-26.1 7.4-38.3 13.1-18.2 8.6-36.3 18.5-51.6 31.6-11.5 9.9-21.1 22.1-29.5 34.7-5.1 7.7-9 15.2-12.6 24.7-3 6.3-4.8 12.7-6.7 19.3-1.5 5.2-3 9.8-3.6 15.7-0.3 1.9-0.8 4.5-1.1 5.7-0.9 3.4-1.3 7.6-0.7 9 0.3 1.3 1.9 1.5 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.7-1.8 1.5-3.1 1.8-2.9 4.4-7 6.9-10.3 9.6-12.2 19.7-24.2 31.5-34.2 14.4-12.3 30.6-22.3 47.2-31.4 18.1-10 36.9-17 56.7-25.4 7.8-3.4 14.4-5.6 23.2-10.3 2.6-1.8 3.7-1.2 2.7 1.4-0.4 0.9-0.7 2.7-0.8 4-0.2 3 0.6 3.7 2.9 2.8 1.8-0.7 2.7-1 7.8-2.6 2.2-0.7 4.1-1.5 4.3-1.9 0.3-0.7-3.8-5-7.9-8.4-2.3-1.9-4.7-4.8-4.3-5.2 0.1-0.1 2 0 3.1 0.1 2.4 0.3 2.9 0.3 10.1 0.5 11.4 0.4 11.6 0.6 10-3.5-1.3-3.3-2.6-6.3-3.9-9.7-0.7-1.3-1.1-2.5-0.9-2.7 0.2-0.2 3.6-0.5 7.9-0.5 4.2 0 8.8-0.2 10.2-0.4l2.5-0.4c1-1-0.1-4.6-0.4-6.9-0.2-1.7-0.8-3.8-1-5.2s-0.4-3.3-0.5-4.2c-0.2-1 0-1.7 0.4-1.9 0.5-0.2 1.4-0.1 2.7 0.5 1.1 0.5 3.2 1.3 4.7 1.9 1.5 0.5 3.8 1.4 5 1.9 2.7 1 4.1 1.1 4.6 0.3 0.5-0.7 1.5-3.4 1.9-5.1 1.4-5.1 11-19.2 13.7-20.1 0.8-0.2 3.4 1.4 4.6 2.4 0.4 0.4 7.6 6 9.2 7.1 1.5 0.9 2.6 0.8 3-0.5 0.1-0.4 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.6 1.8-3.9 3.7-7.2 6.6-14 0.6-2.6 1.5-1.9 5.2 4.1 5.3 8.4 12.5 15.8 21.2 21.6 3.3 2.2 2.6 1.8 4.3 2.7 1.7-0.9 1-0.5 4.3-2.7 8.7-5.8 16-13.2 21.2-21.6 3.8-6 4.7-6.7 5.2-4.1 2.9 6.7 4.8 10.1 6.6 14 0.5 1 1 2.2 1.1 2.6 0.4 1.2 1.5 1.4 3 0.5 1.6-1 8.8-6.7 9.2-7.1 1.2-1.1 3.8-2.7 4.6-2.4 2.7 0.9 12.4 15 13.7 20.1 0.5 1.8 1.5 4.4 1.9 5.1 0.5 0.8 2 0.7 4.6-0.3 1.3-0.5 3.5-1.3 5-1.9 1.5-0.5 3.6-1.4 4.7-1.9 1.3-0.6 2.2-0.8 2.7-0.5 0.5 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.9-0.1 0.9-0.4 2.8-0.5 4.2-0.2 1.4-0.7 3.4-1 5.2-0.3 2.3-1.3 5.9-0.4 6.9l2.5 0.4c1.4 0.2 6 0.4 10.2 0.4 4.3 0 7.8 0.2 7.9 0.5 0.1 0.2-0.3 1.5-0.9 2.7-1.4 3.3-2.7 6.4-3.9 9.7-1.6 4.1-1.4 3.8 10 3.5 7.2-0.2 7.8-0.2 10.1-0.5 1.1-0.1 3-0.2 3.1-0.1 0.4 0.4-1.9 3.2-4.3 5.2-4.1 3.4-8.1 7.7-7.9 8.4 0.1 0.4 2.1 1.2 4.3 1.9 5.1 1.6 6 1.9 7.8 2.6 2.3 0.9 3.1 0.2 2.9-2.8-0.1-1.3-0.4-3.1-0.8-4-1.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 2.7-1.4 8.8 4.8 15.5 7 23.2 10.3 19.9 8.4 38.6 15.4 56.7 25.4 16.5 9.1 32.8 19.1 47.2 31.4 11.8 10.1 21.9 22.1 31.5 34.2 2.6 3.2 5.2 7.3 6.9 10.3 0.8 1.3 1 1.7 1.5 3.1 0.4 1.5 2 1.3 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.2-5.6-0.7-9-0.3-1.3-0.8-3.8-1.1-5.7-0.6-5.9-2.1-10.5-3.6-15.7-1.9-6.5-3.7-13-6.7-19.3-3.6-9.4-7.4-17-12.6-24.7-8.4-12.6-17.9-24.8-29.5-34.7-15.3-13.1-33.4-23-51.6-31.6-12.2-5.7-25.5-8.8-38.3-13.1-19.6-6.4-38.4-12.9-55.9-20.5-7.8-3.4-15.8-6.6-23.1-11-10.6-6.4-19.1-11.2-30-22.1-5.6-5.6-7-7.1-13-14.4-4.9-5.9-8.4-10.8-13.9-19.6-1.9-3.1-5.9-10.8-8.3-16.5-2.8-6.6-5.3-13.4-7.1-20.3-1.1-4.2-1.5-8.6-2.4-12.9-0.6-2.9-1.2-8.6-2-8.5zm-120.2 11.9c-4.1 0-8.1 0.5-12 1.5-10.1 2.7-17.7 8-27.5 15.2-2.3 1.7-3.5 3.1-2.6 3.6 0.4 0.2 8.4-1.8 13.8-2.1 10.7-0.5 21.5 1.6 31.8 4.4 10.7 2.9 20.8 7.9 30.8 12.8 5.7 2.8 10.1 5.5 16.5 9.3 4.9 2.9 4.9 1.3 1.3-4-2.1-3.2-4.2-7.2-6.7-10.6-3.9-5.3-7.7-10.7-12.6-14.9-6.9-5.9-14.7-11.6-23.5-14-3-0.8-6.1-1.2-9.3-1.2zm240.4 0c-3.2 0-6.3 0.4-9.3 1.2-8.8 2.4-16.5 8.1-23.5 14-5 4.2-8.8 9.7-12.6 14.9-2.5 3.4-4.6 7.4-6.7 10.6-3.6 5.3-3.6 6.8 1.3 4 6.5-3.8 10.9-6.5 16.5-9.3 10-4.8 20-9.9 30.8-12.8 10.3-2.8 21.1-4.9 31.8-4.4 5.4 0.3 13.5 2.3 13.8 2.1 0.9-0.6-0.3-2-2.6-3.6-9.8-7.3-17.4-12.5-27.5-15.2-3.9-1-8-1.6-12-1.5zm-263.5 27.1c-7.5 0.1-14.8 2.1-22.2 5-2.8 1.1-12 6.4-14.9 8.6-8 6.1-15.3 13.1-24.4 23.2-7.8 8.7-8.9 10.1-8.9 11.1 0 0.8 2.3 0.5 5.1-0.7 6.1-2.7 13.7-5.8 20.7-8.1 7-2.3 14-4.6 21.2-5.7 7.8-1.2 15.9-1.8 23.8-1.2 8.8 0.7 17.1 4.5 25.9 5.4 10.8 1.1 21.9 1.4 32.6-0.3 5.5-0.8 10.8-3 16-4.9 2.9-1 7.7-3.1 8.5-3.4 1.9-0.7 2.6-1.4 2.3-2.2-0.2-0.5-1.7-0.7-5.9-0.9-9.2-0.5-20.5-3.8-30.3-7.3-5.6-2-10.9-5.1-16.2-7.8-10.8-5.5-19.4-10.7-31.8-10.9-0.5 0-1 0-1.5 0zm285.2 0c-12.4 0.2-20.9 5.4-31.8 10.9-5.4 2.7-10.5 5.8-16.2 7.8-9.8 3.5-21.1 6.8-30.3 7.3-4.2 0.2-5.7 0.4-5.9 0.9-0.3 0.8 0.4 1.5 2.3 2.2 0.8 0.3 5.6 2.4 8.5 3.4 5.3 1.8 10.5 4 16 4.9 10.7 1.6 21.8 1.3 32.6 0.3 8.8-0.9 17.1-4.7 25.9-5.4 7.9-0.6 15.9 0 23.8 1.2 7.2 1.1 14.3 3.4 21.2 5.7 7.1 2.3 14.6 5.4 20.7 8.1 2.8 1.2 5.1 1.5 5.1 0.7 0-1-1.1-2.4-9-11.1-9.1-10.2-16.4-17.1-24.4-23.2-2.9-2.2-12.1-7.5-14.9-8.6-7.9-3.1-15.7-5.1-23.8-5zm-188.9 30.7c-0.8 0.1-2.8 1.5-7 4.8-5.6 4.5-10.1 7-16.2 9.1-7.9 2.7-14 4.1-21.2 5.1-8.7 1.2-17.5 1-26.3 1.1-6.8 0.1-13.6-0.1-20.3-0.2-12.3-0.2-23.9-1.1-37-0.8-8.6 0.5-17.3 0.9-25.6 3-8.1 2-16.1 4.9-23.3 9.2-5.5 3.3-10.3 7.8-14.8 12.5-4.3 4.5-8 9.5-11.2 14.7-3.1 5-5.8 10.4-8 15.9-2.4 5.7-4.1 11.7-5.7 17.7-0.5 1.9-0.9 4.2-1.3 5.9-0.4 1.7-1.2 4.3-1 4.8 0.3 0.9 1.7 0.6 3.3-0.4 0.8-0.5 9.5-6.3 14.4-9.2 8.9-5.1 18.1-9.7 27.4-13.9 6.5-2.9 13.1-5.5 19.9-7.8 14.5-4.9 29.3-9 44.2-12.5 7.8-1.9 15.9-2.6 23.7-4.6 11.4-2.9 22.9-5.7 33.6-10.5 11.7-5.3 22.9-11.9 33.1-19.8 4.1-3.2 8.7-7.9 11-10.9 4.9-6.2 6.3-7.9 7.6-9.7 0.8-1.1 1.5-2.4 1.5-2.7 0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.5-0.7zm94.1 0c-0.4 0-0.5 0.2-0.5 0.7 0 0.4 0.7 1.6 1.5 2.7 1.3 1.8 2.6 3.5 7.6 9.7 2.3 2.9 6.9 7.7 11 10.9 10.2 7.9 21.3 14.6 33.1 19.8 10.7 4.8 22.2 7.6 33.6 10.5 7.8 2 15.9 2.7 23.7 4.6 14.9 3.6 29.7 7.6 44.2 12.5 6.7 2.3 13.4 4.9 19.9 7.8 9.4 4.2 18.5 8.8 27.4 13.9 4.9 2.8 13.6 8.6 14.4 9.2 1.5 1 3 1.3 3.3 0.4 0.1-0.5-0.6-3.1-1-4.8-0.4-1.7-0.8-4-1.3-5.9-1.6-6-3.4-11.9-5.7-17.6-2.3-5.5-4.9-10.8-8-15.9-3.3-5.2-7-10.2-11.3-14.7-4.4-4.7-9.2-9.2-14.8-12.5-7.2-4.3-15.2-7.2-23.3-9.2-8.3-2.1-17-2.5-25.6-3-13.1-0.2-24.7 0.6-37 0.8-6.8 0.1-13.6 0.3-20.3 0.2-8.8-0.1-17.6 0.1-26.3-1.1-7.2-1-13.4-2.4-21.2-5.1-6.1-2.1-10.6-4.6-16.2-9.1-4.2-3.3-6.2-4.8-7-4.8zm-124.5 123.7-5.4 3.6c-3 2-7.9 5.1-10.9 6.8-10.8 6.3-11.8 7-12.2 7.6-0.5 1 1.2 2.9 3.7 4l2.1 0.9 3.7-1.5c2-0.8 4.4-1.5 5.2-1.5 1.4 0 1.6 0.1 2.1 1.8 0.3 1 0.7 2.6 0.9 3.6 0.4 2.4 2.2 3.9 7.3 6.4 6.8 3.3 9.6 4 16.7 4.2 8.9 0.3 8.2-0.1 8.2 4.4 0 2.1-0.3 4.8-0.7 6-0.8 2.6-0.9 4.3-0.3 4.3 0.6 0 4.5-1.7 6.1-2.6 2.6-1.5 2.7-1 2.5 7.5-0.3 11.5-1.5 17.1-8 37.1-2.1 6.7-4.2 13.1-4.6 14.3-0.4 1.2-0.6 2.5-0.4 2.9 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.7 0.6 0.7 1.2 0 13.5-30.8 17.4-43.4 1.9-6.2 3.8-17.7 3.8-23.4 0-1.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-2.7 0.6-0.7 0.7-1.1 0.2-2.8-0.3-1.1-0.8-4.9-1.2-8.4-0.8-7.8-2-11.6-4.3-14-2.2-2.3-7.3-4.4-13-5.3-4.9-0.8-6.3-1.5-6.3-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.3-0.6-1.6-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.1-6.8 4.7-3.6 3.2-5 3.7-5.3 1.8-0.1-0.8 0.6-1.4 3.1-3.2 3.2-2.1 4.6-3.5 4.6-4.6 0-0.3-2-1.4-4.5-2.5l-4.5-2zm155.6 0-4.5 2c-2.5 1.1-4.5 2.2-4.5 2.5 0 1 1.4 2.4 4.6 4.6 2.6 1.7 3.2 2.4 3.1 3.2-0.3 1.9-1.7 1.4-5.3-1.8-5.3-4.7-6-5.3-6.8-4.7-0.3 0.3-0.6 1-0.6 1.6 0 2-1.4 2.7-6.3 3.5-5.7 0.9-10.8 2.9-13 5.3-2.3 2.4-3.5 6.2-4.3 14-0.4 3.5-0.9 7.3-1.2 8.4-0.4 1.7-0.4 2.1 0.2 2.8 0.4 0.5 0.7 1.6 0.7 2.7 0 3.3 0.9 11.1 1.9 15.9 1.4 6.7 2.4 10 7.8 24.4 4.1 10.8 4.7 12.5 8.1 20 1.6 3.6 3.1 6.5 3.3 6.5 0.8 0 0.9-1.4 0.2-3.5-0.4-1.2-2.4-7.6-4.6-14.3-6.4-20-7.6-25.6-8-37.1-0.2-8.5-0.1-8.9 2.5-7.5 1.6 0.9 5.6 2.6 6.1 2.6 0.6 0 0.5-1.7-0.3-4.3-0.4-1.2-0.7-3.9-0.7-6 0-4.5-0.7-4.2 8.2-4.4 7-0.2 9.9-0.9 16.7-4.2 5.1-2.5 6.9-4.1 7.3-6.4 0.2-1 0.6-2.6 0.9-3.6 0.5-1.7 0.7-1.8 2.1-1.8 0.9 0 3.2 0.7 5.2 1.5l3.7 1.5 2.1-0.9c2.4-1.1 4.2-3 3.6-4-0.4-0.6-1.4-1.3-12.2-7.6-3-1.8-7.9-4.8-10.9-6.8l-5.4-3.6zm-220.2 8.8c-0.3 0-1.9 0.9-3.6 2.1-4.4 2.9-11.1 5.9-16.7 8.9-9.7 5.2-19.6 9.9-29.1 15.5-9.9 5.8-19.8 11.8-29.2 18.4-8.8 6.2-17.9 12.2-25.4 19.8-9.3 9.5-17.7 20.1-24 31.8-4.6 8.4-7.6 17.5-9.7 27.1-0.9 1.7-3.3 15.1-4.1 22.7-0.8 7.4-0.9 14.8-0.8 22.2 0.2 9.4 1 18.8 2.2 28.1 0.6 5.2 1.7 10.4 2.7 15.5 0.8 4.2 1.7 8.4 2.6 12.6 0.2 1.1 0.5 3 0.8 3.3 0.7 0.9 2.2 0.7 2.6-0.5 0.2-0.6 0.6-2.9 0.9-5.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-3.7 1.1-5.5 0.9-3.5 1.9-7.1 3-10.5 1.6-5 3.4-10.1 5.5-14.9 3.4-7.7 7.5-15.2 11.8-22.5 2.8-4.7 5.8-9.3 9-13.8 4.3-6 8.8-11.8 13.7-17.4 8.4-9.6 17.4-18.7 26.8-27.3 11-10.1 23.1-19 34.7-28.4 6.7-5.4 13.6-10.7 20.3-16.1 7.1-5.7 12-10.4 15.2-14.8 3.6-4.9 7-12.7 7.3-17.1 0.2-2.5 0.1-2.8-1.4-4.3-4.6-5-7.3-10.2-10.5-16.5-2.1-4.4-3-7-3.3-9-0.3-1.9-1.7-4.2-2.6-4.2zm284.3 0c-0.9 0-2.3 2.3-2.6 4.2-0.3 2-1.3 4.6-3.3 9-3.2 6.3-6 11.5-10.5 16.5-1.5 1.6-1.6 1.8-1.4 4.3 0.3 4.4 3.7 12.2 7.3 17.1 3.2 4.3 8.1 9.1 15.2 14.8 6.7 5.4 13.6 10.7 20.3 16.1 11.6 9.4 23.7 18.3 34.7 28.4 9.4 8.6 18.3 17.8 26.8 27.3 4.9 5.5 9.4 11.4 13.7 17.4 3.2 4.5 6.2 9.1 9 13.8 4.3 7.3 8.3 14.7 11.8 22.5 2.2 4.8 3.9 9.9 5.5 14.9 1.1 3.5 2.1 7 3 10.5 0.4 1.8 0.8 3.2 1.1 5.5 0.3 2.2 0.7 4.5 0.9 5.1 0.4 1.1 1.8 1.4 2.6 0.5 0.3-0.3 0.5-2.2 0.8-3.3 0.9-4.2 1.8-8.4 2.6-12.6 1-5.2 2-10.3 2.7-15.5 1.2-9.3 1.9-18.7 2.1-28.1 0.2-7.4 0-14.8-0.8-22.2-0.8-7.6-3.2-21-4.1-22.7-2.1-9.6-5.1-18.7-9.7-27.1-6.3-11.7-14.7-22.3-24-31.8-7.5-7.7-16.6-13.6-25.4-19.8-9.4-6.6-19.2-12.6-29.2-18.4-9.5-5.5-19.4-10.3-29.1-15.5-5.6-3-12.2-6-16.7-8.9-1.7-1.1-3.3-2.1-3.6-2.1zm-274.8 74.1c-0.5 0-1 0.5-2.2 1.6-1.1 1-3.2 2.9-4.8 4.1-4.4 3.5-11.7 9.5-17.5 14.3-8 6.6-16 13-23.8 19.9-8.7 7.7-17.7 15.3-25.5 23.9-4.3 4.8-8.2 10-11.7 15.5-4.4 7-8.2 14.4-11.3 22.1-3 7.6-5.2 15.4-6.7 23.4-1.5 8.1-2.3 16.4-2.3 24.7 0 11.7 1.3 23.4 3.3 34.9 1.5 8.7 3.8 17.3 6.4 25.7 3.2 10 7.1 19.8 11.4 29.4 4.5 9.9 12.2 24.6 15.1 29 3.2 5.1 5.7 9.6 8.7 14.7 0.9 2 1.9 2.2 2.5 0.6 0.2-0.6 0.4-8.6 0.5-17.6 0-9.1 0-11.7 0.4-17.5 0.6-8.1 1.7-16.2 3.2-24.3 2.2-11.9 5-23.8 8.5-35.4 2.9-9.4 6.2-18.4 10.3-27.6 3.6-8.4 10-21 13.9-27.1 3.6-5.7 7.2-12.3 11.6-17.9 4.3-6.2 9.2-12.1 14.1-17.9 1.4-1.6 10.9-12.3 14.6-16.4 4-4.4 8.1-9.4 11.9-14.1 3-3.8 3.1-3.9 2.9-6.1-0.1-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3-1.3-1.5-1.7-3.5-2.6-5.3-2.2-4.5-3-6.5-6.8-13.6-1.7-3.1-2-3.4-3.4-3.6-1.6-0.1-4.5 0.5-10.1 4.7-5.2 3.8-10.3 8.3-15.2 12.7-4.3 3.4-12.6 11.7-18.3 18.2-6.9 8-13.1 16.7-18.9 25.6-4.8 7.3-9 15.5-13.1 24-3.9 8.8-7.5 17.8-10.5 27-2.1 6.4-3.8 13-5.2 19.7-1.3 6-2.4 11.6-3.2 18.3-0.5 4-1.1 8.2-1.2 9.3-0.1 1.1-0.4 1.9-0.6 1.9-0.6 0-0.7-6-0.4-19.4 0.3-12.6 1.1-18.5 2.7-27.6 1.1-6.2 2.8-12.3 4.8-18.3 3-8.9 6.6-17.6 10.7-26 3-6.1 6.4-11.9 10.1-17.6 5.9-8.9 12.4-17.6 19.4-25.7 7.1-8.1 19.2-19.7 22.9-22.8 4.7-4 8.5-7.2 12.9-10.6 4.1-3.2 4.7-4 4.7-5.5 0-0.7-1.3-3.7-3.5-7.9-0.3-0.6-0.9-2-1.3-3-0.4-1-1.1-2.9-1.7-4.3-0.6-1.4-1.4-3.7-1.8-5.2-0.6-2.1-1.1-2.9-2-3.4-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1-0.4zm265.4 0c-0.3 0-0.6 0.1-1 0.4-0.9 0.5-1.4 1.4-2 3.4-0.4 1.5-1.2 3.9-1.8 5.2-0.6 1.4-1.3 3.3-1.7 4.3-0.4 1-0.9 2.3-1.3 3-2.1 4.2-3.5 7.2-3.5 7.9 0 1.5 0.6 2.3 4.7 5.5 4.3 3.4 8.2 6.6 12.9 10.6 3.7 3.1 15.8 14.7 22.9 22.8 7 8.1 13.5 16.7 19.4 25.7 3.7 5.6 7.1 11.5 10.1 17.6 4.1 8.4 7.7 17.2 10.7 26 2 6 3.7 12.1 4.8 18.3 1.6 9.1 2.4 15 2.7 27.6 0.3 13.4 0.2 19.4-0.4 19.4-0.2 0-0.5-0.9-0.6-1.9-0.1-1.1-0.7-5.2-1.2-9.3-0.9-6.7-1.9-12.2-3.2-18.3-1.5-6.6-3.1-13.2-5.2-19.6-3-9.2-6.6-18.2-10.5-27-4.1-8.5-8.2-16.7-13.1-24-5.9-8.8-12-17.6-18.9-25.6-5.6-6.5-14-14.8-18.3-18.2-4.8-4.3-10-8.9-15.2-12.7-5.7-4.1-8.6-4.8-10.1-4.7-1.4 0.1-1.7 0.4-3.4 3.6-3.8 7.1-4.5 9-6.8 13.6-0.9 1.7-1.3 3.8-2.6 5.3-0.4 0.5-0.8 1.8-0.9 3-0.2 2.1-0.1 2.3 2.9 6.1 3.8 4.8 7.9 9.7 11.9 14.1 3.7 4.1 13.2 14.8 14.6 16.4 4.9 5.8 9.7 11.7 14.1 17.9 4.3 5.5 8 12.2 11.6 17.9 3.9 6.1 10.3 18.8 13.9 27.1 4 9.2 7.4 18.2 10.3 27.6 3.5 11.6 6.3 23.5 8.5 35.4 1.5 8 2.6 16.1 3.2 24.3 0.5 5.8 0.4 8.4 0.4 17.5 0 9.1 0.2 17 0.5 17.7 0.6 1.6 1.6 1.4 2.5-0.6 3-5.1 5.5-9.7 8.7-14.7 2.8-4.4 10.6-19.1 15.1-29 4.3-9.6 8.2-19.4 11.4-29.4 2.7-8.4 5-17 6.4-25.7 2-11.5 3.2-23.2 3.3-34.9 0-8.3-0.7-16.6-2.3-24.7-1.5-8-3.7-15.9-6.7-23.4-3-7.7-6.9-15.1-11.3-22.1-3.4-5.5-7.4-10.7-11.7-15.5-7.8-8.7-16.8-16.2-25.5-23.9-7.7-6.8-15.8-13.3-23.8-19.9-5.8-4.8-13.1-10.9-17.5-14.3-1.5-1.2-3.7-3.1-4.8-4.1-1.2-1.2-1.7-1.6-2.2-1.6zm-183.4 42c-0.9 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 3.3 0.2 2.7 0.7 4.1 2.6 7.9 1.6 3.1 2.8 5 4 5.9 1.9 1.5 10.2 5.7 16.8 8.5 8.7 3.6 10.1 4.2 16.2 7.2 3.4 1.7 6.7 3.8 7.7 4.5 1 0.6 1.4 2 1.4 3.4l0.1 9.7 0.2 8.5c0.1 1.2 0.1 2.2-1.2 3.5 0 0-2.3 2.1-3.5 3.1-4.5 3.7-8.7 7.8-13.8 10.5-4.5 2.4-9.4 4.6-14.5 4.9-5 0.3-8.4-0.7-14.6-3.1-2.6-1-5-1.7-5.4-1.6-0.9 0.4-2.5 5.9-2.5 8.9 0 5.3 2.5 10.9 6.3 14.5 1.4 1.4 3 2.4 3.5 2.4 0.7 0 4.8-4.8 7.4-6.9 5.7-4.4 11.4-9 18.1-11.6 7.1-2.8 14.1-4.1 22.5-4 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 8.5-0.1 15.4 1.2 22.5 4 6.7 2.6 12.4 7.2 18.1 11.6 2.7 2.1 6.8 6.9 7.4 6.9 0.6 0 2.1-1 3.5-2.4 3.8-3.6 6.3-9.3 6.3-14.5 0-3-1.6-8.6-2.5-8.9-0.4-0.1-2.8 0.6-5.4 1.6-6.2 2.4-9.6 3.4-14.6 3.1-5.1-0.3-10-2.5-14.5-4.9-5.1-2.7-9.3-6.8-13.8-10.5-1.2-1-3.5-3.1-3.5-3.1-1.2-1.3-1.2-2.2-1.2-3.5l0.2-8.5 0.1-9.7c0-1.4 0.4-2.7 1.4-3.4 1-0.6 4.3-2.8 7.7-4.5 6.1-3 7.5-3.6 16.2-7.2 6.6-2.8 14.9-6.9 16.8-8.5 1.1-0.9 2.4-2.8 4-5.9 1.9-3.8 2.4-5.2 2.6-7.9 0.3-3.1 0.2-3.3-0.7-3.3-0.5 0-2.4 1.3-4.2 2.8-1.8 1.6-4.4 3.4-5.9 4-2.5 1.1-3.1 1.2-10.2 1.2-6.3 0-7.7 0.1-8.7 0.8-2.9 1.9-10 4.4-14.5 5.1-2.9 0.5-5.1 0.7-7.3 0.7-2.2 0-4.4-0.2-7.3-0.7-4.5-0.7-11.6-3.2-14.5-5.1-1-0.7-2.4-0.8-8.7-0.8-7.1 0-7.7-0.1-10.2-1.2-1.5-0.6-4.1-2.4-5.9-4-1.8-1.6-3.6-2.8-4.2-2.8zm-29.3 10.1c-1.7 0-1.9 1.9 0.4 5.2 3 4.3 5.2 6.3 8.3 8.8 3.3 2.6 7 5.1 11 6.4 3.3 1.1 6.9 1 10.4 1.1 2.6 0 7.7-0.4 7.9-0.7 0.6-1-1-2-2.4-2.3-3.2-0.6-10.4-2-15.2-4.2-4.7-2.1-9.5-5.3-12.8-8.6-3.3-3.2-6.1-5.8-7.7-5.8zm-7.1 3.8c-0.3 0-0.6 0.2-0.9 0.5-0.6 0.6-0.5 1.2 1.3 5.2 3.3 7.6 6.9 13.1 12.3 17.9 3.5 3.1 8 5.4 12.6 6.5 5.4 1.3 10.1 0.6 16.7-0.3 4.7-0.6 10-1.4 15.1-1.4 4.2 0 11.6 1.3 12.6 1.3 1.7 0.1 1.8 0 2-1.1 0.1-1.2-1.3-2.4-5.7-4.8-5.2-2.8-12.2-3.5-20.4-2-5.9 1-14.8 1.3-18.1 0.6-8.6-2-14.6-6.7-23.1-18.2-2.2-3-3.3-4.2-4.3-4.1zm-7.5 23.2c-0.6 0-1.5 1.1-3.1 3-1.4 1.7-4.5 5.4-7.1 8.3-8.4 9.6-18.6 21.7-25.8 34.7-5 8.6-11.2 21.1-13 26-2.5 6.8-5.6 13.4-7.6 20.8-3.6 11.4-6.9 25-8.7 37.7-2.3 16.8-2.4 34.6-2.3 50.9 0.9 9.5 1.6 19.2 3.8 28.6 3.1 13.1 6.4 25.7 13 38.3 2.2 3.5 4.9 8.1 7.9 11.7 2.3 2.8 3.7 3.7 4.4 2.6 0.3-0.4-0.4-3.6-1.4-6.7-0.9-2.8-1.1-6-1.9-8.9-0.8-3.3-1.8-12.1-2.5-22.1-0.6-9 0.5-26.1 2.4-35 1.5-7.2 2.2-15.6 4.6-23.1 4-18.1 11.4-36.3 19.2-53 4.4-9.2 10.1-19.8 15.6-29.3 6.5-10.9 14.4-23.2 22.1-34 2-2.9 4.2-5.6 5.8-8.6-3.9-2.9-7.9-5.8-11.2-8.3-4.3-3.4-8-8.1-9.9-12.5-1.1-2.5-1.6-5.1-2.9-15.3-0.5-4.1-0.8-5.9-1.6-5.9zm189.3 0c-0.8 0-1 1.8-1.6 5.9-1.3 10.2-1.8 12.8-2.9 15.3-1.9 4.4-5.6 9.1-9.9 12.5-3.3 2.6-7.3 5.5-11.1 8.3 1.6 3 3.8 5.6 5.8 8.6 7.7 10.9 15.6 23.1 22.1 34 5.6 9.6 11.3 20.1 15.6 29.3 7.8 16.8 15.2 35 19.2 53 2.4 7.4 3.1 15.9 4.6 23.1 1.9 9 3 26.1 2.4 35-0.7 10-1.7 18.8-2.5 22.1-0.8 2.9-1 6-1.9 8.9-1 3.1-1.6 6.2-1.4 6.7 0.6 1 2.1 0.2 4.4-2.6 3-3.5 5.6-8.1 7.9-11.7 6.6-12.6 10-25.2 13-38.3 2.2-9.4 2.9-19.1 3.8-28.6 0-16.3 0-34.1-2.3-50.9-1.7-12.8-5.1-26.3-8.7-37.7-2-7.4-5-14-7.6-20.8-1.8-4.9-8-17.4-13-26-7.2-13-17.4-25.1-25.8-34.7-2.5-2.9-5.7-6.6-7.1-8.3-1.6-1.9-2.5-3-3.1-3zm-63.7 16.3c-1.4 0-2 0.6-2 1.8 0 1.3 11.5 6.3 16 6.9 3.8 0.6 7.7-0.2 12.3-2.2 5.8-2.6 7.3-3.6 7.3-4.9 0-1.6-0.8-1.6-5.2-0.3-3.3 1-5 1.2-9.3 1.2-6.7 0-12-0.6-15.8-1.8-1.3-0.4-2.4-0.6-3.2-0.6zm-98.6 49.1c-0.1 0-0.2 0.1-0.3 0.2-0.2 0.2-5.2 8.6-11.2 18.7-15.5 26.2-18.7 33.9-25.4 51.9-4.1 11.1-7.6 22.7-8.9 34.4-2.1 19.2-2.1 39.1 2.1 58 3.7 16.8 6.6 27 20.2 47.5 3.4 5.1 5.4 7.4 8.7 10.7 0.3 0.3 0.7 0.6 1.2 0.6 1.5 0 1-1 0.8-2.4-1.2-9.9-1.7-34.9-1.2-57.9 0.5-22.1 2.2-45.4 5.2-67.9 1.9-13.9 4.9-27.6 8.1-41.4 1.8-6.9 5.8-21.1 9.4-32.7 1.3-4.4 1.4-4.1-3-11.9-3.5-6.1-4.8-8.1-5.7-7.9zm135.2 0c-0.9 0.1-2.3 2.2-5.5 7.9-4.4 7.8-4.3 7.5-3 11.9 3.6 11.6 7.6 25.7 9.4 32.7 3.2 13.7 6.2 27.4 8.1 41.4 3 22.5 4.7 45.8 5.2 67.9 0.5 23.1 0 48.1-1.2 57.9-0.2 1.4-0.6 2.4 0.8 2.4 0.4 0 0.9-0.3 1.2-0.6 3.3-3.3 5.3-5.6 8.7-10.7 13.6-20.5 16.5-30.7 20.2-47.5 4.2-18.9 4.2-38.8 2.1-58-1.3-11.8-4.8-23.3-8.9-34.4-6.7-18.1-9.8-25.7-25.4-51.9-5.9-10.1-11-18.4-11.2-18.7-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2zm-109 24.6c-0.3 0-0.7 0.7-1.1 1.5-3.7 8.4-5.8 16.7-7.8 25.3-2.3 9.8-3.6 19.9-4.9 30-0.9 7.1-0.8 5.3-1.9 21.4-0.7 10.4-0.6 14.4 0.6 26 0.9 8.9 1.5 11.7 2.9 17.4 1.6 6.5 3.2 12.9 6.5 19 4.5 8.7 11.7 16.9 19.9 22.6 1.8 1.3 3.7 2.3 4.3 2.3 1.3 0 1.6-0.8 0.9-2.7-0.5-1-0.8-1.9-1.2-2.8-2.7-7.8-4.6-15.8-6.6-23.7-1.6-6.4-2.9-12.8-4.2-19.2-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.2-3.2-18.3-1-7.1-2-14.1-2.5-21.2-0.8-12.3-1.3-27.1-1.5-40.4-0.1-11.6 0-22.1 0.5-28.8 0.4-5.9 0.2-8.2-0.8-8.2zm83 0c-1 0-1.2 2.3-0.8 8.2 0.5 6.8 0.6 17.3 0.5 28.8-0.2 13.3-0.7 28.1-1.5 40.4-0.5 7.1-1.4 14.2-2.5 21.2-0.9 6.1-2 12.2-3.2 18.3-1.3 6.4-2.6 12.8-4.2 19.2-2 8-3.9 16-6.6 23.7-0.3 1-0.7 1.8-1.2 2.8-0.7 1.8-0.4 2.7 0.9 2.7 0.5 0 2.5-1 4.3-2.3 8.3-5.8 15.5-14 19.9-22.6 3.3-6.1 4.9-12.5 6.5-19 1.4-5.7 2-8.5 2.9-17.4 1.2-11.6 1.3-15.6 0.6-26-1.1-16.1-1-14.3-1.9-21.4-1.3-10-2.5-20.1-4.9-30-2-8.6-4.1-16.9-7.8-25.3-0.3-0.8-0.8-1.5-1.1-1.5zm-44.1 5.9c-13.8 0-14.7 0.1-15.2 0.9-0.7 1 0.2 15.1 0.5 22.7 0.3 8 0.9 16.1 1.4 24.1 0.6 8.7 1.2 17.3 2.2 26 0.8 7.4 1.4 14.8 3.1 22 1.5 6.7 3.8 13.2 6.3 19.6 1.2 3.1 3.3 8.3 4.3 9.1 1-0.9 3.1-6 4.3-9.1 2.5-6.4 4.8-12.9 6.3-19.6 1.7-7.2 2.3-14.6 3.1-22 1-8.6 1.5-17.3 2.2-26 0.6-8 1.1-16.1 1.4-24.1 0.3-7.6 1.2-21.7 0.5-22.7-0.5-0.8-1.4-0.8-15.2-0.9-1.3 0.1-2 0.1-2.6 0.1-0.7 0-1.3 0-2.6-0.1z">
  <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0.1s;f1.end+1s" values="2000;0;2000" dur="15s" 
  calcMode="linear"/> 
  <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin="p1.end+1s" values="#E3FFF0; black; #E3FFF0" dur="15s"  
  calcMode="linear" />
 </path>
    </g>
  
</svg> 
</div>
```

Как сделать тот же самый эффект рисования линий при прокрутке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На нативном js

```js
const htmlElem = document.querySelector('html');
//Переменная для 'stroke-dashoffset' 
const pathElem = document.querySelector('.path');
const dashOffset = parseInt(getComputedStyle(pathElem).strokeDashoffset);

//на событие прокрутки - выполнить функцию
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  //рассчитать, как далеко вниз по прокручена страница 
  const percentageComplete = window.pageYOffset / (htmlElem.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100;
  //получить значение, которое будет вычтено из 'stroke-dashoffset'
  const offsetUnit = percentageComplete * dashOffset / 100;
  //установить новое значение dashoffset, чтобы создать эффект рисования
  pathElem.style.strokeDashoffset = dashOffset - offsetUnit;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%);
  //color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  letter-spacing: .09em;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.Lion {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Нарисуйте голову льва при прокрутке</h1>
<div class="Lion"></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
   <g> 
            
       <path class="path"  d="m272.2 113.6c-0.3 0-0.6 0-0.9 0.1-0.7 0.1 2.2 2.5 10.9 11.2 9.8 9.7 18.2 19.1 23 25.5 5.9 8.1 12.3 18.6 16.4 29.1 0.8 1.6 3.6 11.9 4.6 16.9 0.5 2.8 1 5.4 1.2 5.8 0.8 2.5 3.9-8.4 4.8-13 1.2-5.6 1.2-11.4 1-17.1-0.2-5.8-0.5-11.8-2.2-17.4-1.4-4.8-3.6-9.4-6.7-13.3-6.6-8.2-15.1-15.1-24.4-20.1-6.4-3.5-13.8-4.9-20.9-6.5-2.2-0.5-4.8-1.3-6.9-1.2zm194.7 0c-2.1 0-4.7 0.7-6.9 1.2-7.1 1.6-14.5 3.1-20.9 6.5-9.3 5-17.8 11.8-24.4 20.1-3.1 3.9-5.3 8.6-6.7 13.3-1.7 5.6-2 11.5-2.2 17.4-0.2 5.7-0.1 11.5 1 17.1 1 4.5 4 15.4 4.8 13 0.1-0.3 0.6-2.9 1.2-5.8 0.9-5 3.7-15.3 4.6-16.9 4.2-10.5 10.5-21 16.5-29.1 4.8-6.5 13.2-15.8 23-25.5 8.7-8.7 11.6-11.1 10.9-11.2-0.3 0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.1zm-97.3 24.5c-0.8-0.1-1.4 5.7-2 8.5-0.9 4.3-1.3 8.7-2.4 12.9-1.8 6.9-4.3 13.7-7.1 20.3-2.4 5.7-6.4 13.4-8.3 16.5-5.5 8.8-9 13.7-13.9 19.6-6.1 7.3-7.4 8.8-13 14.4-10.8 10.8-19.3 15.7-30 22.1-7.3 4.4-15.3 7.6-23.1 11-17.5 7.6-36.3 14.2-55.9 20.5-12.8 4.3-26.1 7.4-38.3 13.1-18.2 8.6-36.3 18.5-51.6 31.6-11.5 9.9-21.1 22.1-29.5 34.7-5.1 7.7-9 15.2-12.6 24.7-3 6.3-4.8 12.7-6.7 19.3-1.5 5.2-3 9.8-3.6 15.7-0.3 1.9-0.8 4.5-1.1 5.7-0.9 3.4-1.3 7.6-0.7 9 0.3 1.3 1.9 1.5 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.7-1.8 1.5-3.1 1.8-2.9 4.4-7 6.9-10.3 9.6-12.2 19.7-24.2 31.5-34.2 14.4-12.3 30.6-22.3 47.2-31.4 18.1-10 36.9-17 56.7-25.4 7.8-3.4 14.4-5.6 23.2-10.3 2.6-1.8 3.7-1.2 2.7 1.4-0.4 0.9-0.7 2.7-0.8 4-0.2 3 0.6 3.7 2.9 2.8 1.8-0.7 2.7-1 7.8-2.6 2.2-0.7 4.1-1.5 4.3-1.9 0.3-0.7-3.8-5-7.9-8.4-2.3-1.9-4.7-4.8-4.3-5.2 0.1-0.1 2 0 3.1 0.1 2.4 0.3 2.9 0.3 10.1 0.5 11.4 0.4 11.6 0.6 10-3.5-1.3-3.3-2.6-6.3-3.9-9.7-0.7-1.3-1.1-2.5-0.9-2.7 0.2-0.2 3.6-0.5 7.9-0.5 4.2 0 8.8-0.2 10.2-0.4l2.5-0.4c1-1-0.1-4.6-0.4-6.9-0.2-1.7-0.8-3.8-1-5.2s-0.4-3.3-0.5-4.2c-0.2-1 0-1.7 0.4-1.9 0.5-0.2 1.4-0.1 2.7 0.5 1.1 0.5 3.2 1.3 4.7 1.9 1.5 0.5 3.8 1.4 5 1.9 2.7 1 4.1 1.1 4.6 0.3 0.5-0.7 1.5-3.4 1.9-5.1 1.4-5.1 11-19.2 13.7-20.1 0.8-0.2 3.4 1.4 4.6 2.4 0.4 0.4 7.6 6 9.2 7.1 1.5 0.9 2.6 0.8 3-0.5 0.1-0.4 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.6 1.8-3.9 3.7-7.2 6.6-14 0.6-2.6 1.5-1.9 5.2 4.1 5.3 8.4 12.5 15.8 21.2 21.6 3.3 2.2 2.6 1.8 4.3 2.7 1.7-0.9 1-0.5 4.3-2.7 8.7-5.8 16-13.2 21.2-21.6 3.8-6 4.7-6.7 5.2-4.1 2.9 6.7 4.8 10.1 6.6 14 0.5 1 1 2.2 1.1 2.6 0.4 1.2 1.5 1.4 3 0.5 1.6-1 8.8-6.7 9.2-7.1 1.2-1.1 3.8-2.7 4.6-2.4 2.7 0.9 12.4 15 13.7 20.1 0.5 1.8 1.5 4.4 1.9 5.1 0.5 0.8 2 0.7 4.6-0.3 1.3-0.5 3.5-1.3 5-1.9 1.5-0.5 3.6-1.4 4.7-1.9 1.3-0.6 2.2-0.8 2.7-0.5 0.5 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.9-0.1 0.9-0.4 2.8-0.5 4.2-0.2 1.4-0.7 3.4-1 5.2-0.3 2.3-1.3 5.9-0.4 6.9l2.5 0.4c1.4 0.2 6 0.4 10.2 0.4 4.3 0 7.8 0.2 7.9 0.5 0.1 0.2-0.3 1.5-0.9 2.7-1.4 3.3-2.7 6.4-3.9 9.7-1.6 4.1-1.4 3.8 10 3.5 7.2-0.2 7.8-0.2 10.1-0.5 1.1-0.1 3-0.2 3.1-0.1 0.4 0.4-1.9 3.2-4.3 5.2-4.1 3.4-8.1 7.7-7.9 8.4 0.1 0.4 2.1 1.2 4.3 1.9 5.1 1.6 6 1.9 7.8 2.6 2.3 0.9 3.1 0.2 2.9-2.8-0.1-1.3-0.4-3.1-0.8-4-1.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 2.7-1.4 8.8 4.8 15.5 7 23.2 10.3 19.9 8.4 38.6 15.4 56.7 25.4 16.5 9.1 32.8 19.1 47.2 31.4 11.8 10.1 21.9 22.1 31.5 34.2 2.6 3.2 5.2 7.3 6.9 10.3 0.8 1.3 1 1.7 1.5 3.1 0.4 1.5 2 1.3 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.2-5.6-0.7-9-0.3-1.3-0.8-3.8-1.1-5.7-0.6-5.9-2.1-10.5-3.6-15.7-1.9-6.5-3.7-13-6.7-19.3-3.6-9.4-7.4-17-12.6-24.7-8.4-12.6-17.9-24.8-29.5-34.7-15.3-13.1-33.4-23-51.6-31.6-12.2-5.7-25.5-8.8-38.3-13.1-19.6-6.4-38.4-12.9-55.9-20.5-7.8-3.4-15.8-6.6-23.1-11-10.6-6.4-19.1-11.2-30-22.1-5.6-5.6-7-7.1-13-14.4-4.9-5.9-8.4-10.8-13.9-19.6-1.9-3.1-5.9-10.8-8.3-16.5-2.8-6.6-5.3-13.4-7.1-20.3-1.1-4.2-1.5-8.6-2.4-12.9-0.6-2.9-1.2-8.6-2-8.5zm-120.2 11.9c-4.1 0-8.1 0.5-12 1.5-10.1 2.7-17.7 8-27.5 15.2-2.3 1.7-3.5 3.1-2.6 3.6 0.4 0.2 8.4-1.8 13.8-2.1 10.7-0.5 21.5 1.6 31.8 4.4 10.7 2.9 20.8 7.9 30.8 12.8 5.7 2.8 10.1 5.5 16.5 9.3 4.9 2.9 4.9 1.3 1.3-4-2.1-3.2-4.2-7.2-6.7-10.6-3.9-5.3-7.7-10.7-12.6-14.9-6.9-5.9-14.7-11.6-23.5-14-3-0.8-6.1-1.2-9.3-1.2zm240.4 0c-3.2 0-6.3 0.4-9.3 1.2-8.8 2.4-16.5 8.1-23.5 14-5 4.2-8.8 9.7-12.6 14.9-2.5 3.4-4.6 7.4-6.7 10.6-3.6 5.3-3.6 6.8 1.3 4 6.5-3.8 10.9-6.5 16.5-9.3 10-4.8 20-9.9 30.8-12.8 10.3-2.8 21.1-4.9 31.8-4.4 5.4 0.3 13.5 2.3 13.8 2.1 0.9-0.6-0.3-2-2.6-3.6-9.8-7.3-17.4-12.5-27.5-15.2-3.9-1-8-1.6-12-1.5zm-263.5 27.1c-7.5 0.1-14.8 2.1-22.2 5-2.8 1.1-12 6.4-14.9 8.6-8 6.1-15.3 13.1-24.4 23.2-7.8 8.7-8.9 10.1-8.9 11.1 0 0.8 2.3 0.5 5.1-0.7 6.1-2.7 13.7-5.8 20.7-8.1 7-2.3 14-4.6 21.2-5.7 7.8-1.2 15.9-1.8 23.8-1.2 8.8 0.7 17.1 4.5 25.9 5.4 10.8 1.1 21.9 1.4 32.6-0.3 5.5-0.8 10.8-3 16-4.9 2.9-1 7.7-3.1 8.5-3.4 1.9-0.7 2.6-1.4 2.3-2.2-0.2-0.5-1.7-0.7-5.9-0.9-9.2-0.5-20.5-3.8-30.3-7.3-5.6-2-10.9-5.1-16.2-7.8-10.8-5.5-19.4-10.7-31.8-10.9-0.5 0-1 0-1.5 0zm285.2 0c-12.4 0.2-20.9 5.4-31.8 10.9-5.4 2.7-10.5 5.8-16.2 7.8-9.8 3.5-21.1 6.8-30.3 7.3-4.2 0.2-5.7 0.4-5.9 0.9-0.3 0.8 0.4 1.5 2.3 2.2 0.8 0.3 5.6 2.4 8.5 3.4 5.3 1.8 10.5 4 16 4.9 10.7 1.6 21.8 1.3 32.6 0.3 8.8-0.9 17.1-4.7 25.9-5.4 7.9-0.6 15.9 0 23.8 1.2 7.2 1.1 14.3 3.4 21.2 5.7 7.1 2.3 14.6 5.4 20.7 8.1 2.8 1.2 5.1 1.5 5.1 0.7 0-1-1.1-2.4-9-11.1-9.1-10.2-16.4-17.1-24.4-23.2-2.9-2.2-12.1-7.5-14.9-8.6-7.9-3.1-15.7-5.1-23.8-5zm-188.9 30.7c-0.8 0.1-2.8 1.5-7 4.8-5.6 4.5-10.1 7-16.2 9.1-7.9 2.7-14 4.1-21.2 5.1-8.7 1.2-17.5 1-26.3 1.1-6.8 0.1-13.6-0.1-20.3-0.2-12.3-0.2-23.9-1.1-37-0.8-8.6 0.5-17.3 0.9-25.6 3-8.1 2-16.1 4.9-23.3 9.2-5.5 3.3-10.3 7.8-14.8 12.5-4.3 4.5-8 9.5-11.2 14.7-3.1 5-5.8 10.4-8 15.9-2.4 5.7-4.1 11.7-5.7 17.7-0.5 1.9-0.9 4.2-1.3 5.9-0.4 1.7-1.2 4.3-1 4.8 0.3 0.9 1.7 0.6 3.3-0.4 0.8-0.5 9.5-6.3 14.4-9.2 8.9-5.1 18.1-9.7 27.4-13.9 6.5-2.9 13.1-5.5 19.9-7.8 14.5-4.9 29.3-9 44.2-12.5 7.8-1.9 15.9-2.6 23.7-4.6 11.4-2.9 22.9-5.7 33.6-10.5 11.7-5.3 22.9-11.9 33.1-19.8 4.1-3.2 8.7-7.9 11-10.9 4.9-6.2 6.3-7.9 7.6-9.7 0.8-1.1 1.5-2.4 1.5-2.7 0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.5-0.7zm94.1 0c-0.4 0-0.5 0.2-0.5 0.7 0 0.4 0.7 1.6 1.5 2.7 1.3 1.8 2.6 3.5 7.6 9.7 2.3 2.9 6.9 7.7 11 10.9 10.2 7.9 21.3 14.6 33.1 19.8 10.7 4.8 22.2 7.6 33.6 10.5 7.8 2 15.9 2.7 23.7 4.6 14.9 3.6 29.7 7.6 44.2 12.5 6.7 2.3 13.4 4.9 19.9 7.8 9.4 4.2 18.5 8.8 27.4 13.9 4.9 2.8 13.6 8.6 14.4 9.2 1.5 1 3 1.3 3.3 0.4 0.1-0.5-0.6-3.1-1-4.8-0.4-1.7-0.8-4-1.3-5.9-1.6-6-3.4-11.9-5.7-17.6-2.3-5.5-4.9-10.8-8-15.9-3.3-5.2-7-10.2-11.3-14.7-4.4-4.7-9.2-9.2-14.8-12.5-7.2-4.3-15.2-7.2-23.3-9.2-8.3-2.1-17-2.5-25.6-3-13.1-0.2-24.7 0.6-37 0.8-6.8 0.1-13.6 0.3-20.3 0.2-8.8-0.1-17.6 0.1-26.3-1.1-7.2-1-13.4-2.4-21.2-5.1-6.1-2.1-10.6-4.6-16.2-9.1-4.2-3.3-6.2-4.8-7-4.8zm-124.5 123.7-5.4 3.6c-3 2-7.9 5.1-10.9 6.8-10.8 6.3-11.8 7-12.2 7.6-0.5 1 1.2 2.9 3.7 4l2.1 0.9 3.7-1.5c2-0.8 4.4-1.5 5.2-1.5 1.4 0 1.6 0.1 2.1 1.8 0.3 1 0.7 2.6 0.9 3.6 0.4 2.4 2.2 3.9 7.3 6.4 6.8 3.3 9.6 4 16.7 4.2 8.9 0.3 8.2-0.1 8.2 4.4 0 2.1-0.3 4.8-0.7 6-0.8 2.6-0.9 4.3-0.3 4.3 0.6 0 4.5-1.7 6.1-2.6 2.6-1.5 2.7-1 2.5 7.5-0.3 11.5-1.5 17.1-8 37.1-2.1 6.7-4.2 13.1-4.6 14.3-0.4 1.2-0.6 2.5-0.4 2.9 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.7 0.6 0.7 1.2 0 13.5-30.8 17.4-43.4 1.9-6.2 3.8-17.7 3.8-23.4 0-1.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-2.7 0.6-0.7 0.7-1.1 0.2-2.8-0.3-1.1-0.8-4.9-1.2-8.4-0.8-7.8-2-11.6-4.3-14-2.2-2.3-7.3-4.4-13-5.3-4.9-0.8-6.3-1.5-6.3-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.3-0.6-1.6-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.1-6.8 4.7-3.6 3.2-5 3.7-5.3 1.8-0.1-0.8 0.6-1.4 3.1-3.2 3.2-2.1 4.6-3.5 4.6-4.6 0-0.3-2-1.4-4.5-2.5l-4.5-2zm155.6 0-4.5 2c-2.5 1.1-4.5 2.2-4.5 2.5 0 1 1.4 2.4 4.6 4.6 2.6 1.7 3.2 2.4 3.1 3.2-0.3 1.9-1.7 1.4-5.3-1.8-5.3-4.7-6-5.3-6.8-4.7-0.3 0.3-0.6 1-0.6 1.6 0 2-1.4 2.7-6.3 3.5-5.7 0.9-10.8 2.9-13 5.3-2.3 2.4-3.5 6.2-4.3 14-0.4 3.5-0.9 7.3-1.2 8.4-0.4 1.7-0.4 2.1 0.2 2.8 0.4 0.5 0.7 1.6 0.7 2.7 0 3.3 0.9 11.1 1.9 15.9 1.4 6.7 2.4 10 7.8 24.4 4.1 10.8 4.7 12.5 8.1 20 1.6 3.6 3.1 6.5 3.3 6.5 0.8 0 0.9-1.4 0.2-3.5-0.4-1.2-2.4-7.6-4.6-14.3-6.4-20-7.6-25.6-8-37.1-0.2-8.5-0.1-8.9 2.5-7.5 1.6 0.9 5.6 2.6 6.1 2.6 0.6 0 0.5-1.7-0.3-4.3-0.4-1.2-0.7-3.9-0.7-6 0-4.5-0.7-4.2 8.2-4.4 7-0.2 9.9-0.9 16.7-4.2 5.1-2.5 6.9-4.1 7.3-6.4 0.2-1 0.6-2.6 0.9-3.6 0.5-1.7 0.7-1.8 2.1-1.8 0.9 0 3.2 0.7 5.2 1.5l3.7 1.5 2.1-0.9c2.4-1.1 4.2-3 3.6-4-0.4-0.6-1.4-1.3-12.2-7.6-3-1.8-7.9-4.8-10.9-6.8l-5.4-3.6zm-220.2 8.8c-0.3 0-1.9 0.9-3.6 2.1-4.4 2.9-11.1 5.9-16.7 8.9-9.7 5.2-19.6 9.9-29.1 15.5-9.9 5.8-19.8 11.8-29.2 18.4-8.8 6.2-17.9 12.2-25.4 19.8-9.3 9.5-17.7 20.1-24 31.8-4.6 8.4-7.6 17.5-9.7 27.1-0.9 1.7-3.3 15.1-4.1 22.7-0.8 7.4-0.9 14.8-0.8 22.2 0.2 9.4 1 18.8 2.2 28.1 0.6 5.2 1.7 10.4 2.7 15.5 0.8 4.2 1.7 8.4 2.6 12.6 0.2 1.1 0.5 3 0.8 3.3 0.7 0.9 2.2 0.7 2.6-0.5 0.2-0.6 0.6-2.9 0.9-5.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-3.7 1.1-5.5 0.9-3.5 1.9-7.1 3-10.5 1.6-5 3.4-10.1 5.5-14.9 3.4-7.7 7.5-15.2 11.8-22.5 2.8-4.7 5.8-9.3 9-13.8 4.3-6 8.8-11.8 13.7-17.4 8.4-9.6 17.4-18.7 26.8-27.3 11-10.1 23.1-19 34.7-28.4 6.7-5.4 13.6-10.7 20.3-16.1 7.1-5.7 12-10.4 15.2-14.8 3.6-4.9 7-12.7 7.3-17.1 0.2-2.5 0.1-2.8-1.4-4.3-4.6-5-7.3-10.2-10.5-16.5-2.1-4.4-3-7-3.3-9-0.3-1.9-1.7-4.2-2.6-4.2zm284.3 0c-0.9 0-2.3 2.3-2.6 4.2-0.3 2-1.3 4.6-3.3 9-3.2 6.3-6 11.5-10.5 16.5-1.5 1.6-1.6 1.8-1.4 4.3 0.3 4.4 3.7 12.2 7.3 17.1 3.2 4.3 8.1 9.1 15.2 14.8 6.7 5.4 13.6 10.7 20.3 16.1 11.6 9.4 23.7 18.3 34.7 28.4 9.4 8.6 18.3 17.8 26.8 27.3 4.9 5.5 9.4 11.4 13.7 17.4 3.2 4.5 6.2 9.1 9 13.8 4.3 7.3 8.3 14.7 11.8 22.5 2.2 4.8 3.9 9.9 5.5 14.9 1.1 3.5 2.1 7 3 10.5 0.4 1.8 0.8 3.2 1.1 5.5 0.3 2.2 0.7 4.5 0.9 5.1 0.4 1.1 1.8 1.4 2.6 0.5 0.3-0.3 0.5-2.2 0.8-3.3 0.9-4.2 1.8-8.4 2.6-12.6 1-5.2 2-10.3 2.7-15.5 1.2-9.3 1.9-18.7 2.1-28.1 0.2-7.4 0-14.8-0.8-22.2-0.8-7.6-3.2-21-4.1-22.7-2.1-9.6-5.1-18.7-9.7-27.1-6.3-11.7-14.7-22.3-24-31.8-7.5-7.7-16.6-13.6-25.4-19.8-9.4-6.6-19.2-12.6-29.2-18.4-9.5-5.5-19.4-10.3-29.1-15.5-5.6-3-12.2-6-16.7-8.9-1.7-1.1-3.3-2.1-3.6-2.1zm-274.8 74.1c-0.5 0-1 0.5-2.2 1.6-1.1 1-3.2 2.9-4.8 4.1-4.4 3.5-11.7 9.5-17.5 14.3-8 6.6-16 13-23.8 19.9-8.7 7.7-17.7 15.3-25.5 23.9-4.3 4.8-8.2 10-11.7 15.5-4.4 7-8.2 14.4-11.3 22.1-3 7.6-5.2 15.4-6.7 23.4-1.5 8.1-2.3 16.4-2.3 24.7 0 11.7 1.3 23.4 3.3 34.9 1.5 8.7 3.8 17.3 6.4 25.7 3.2 10 7.1 19.8 11.4 29.4 4.5 9.9 12.2 24.6 15.1 29 3.2 5.1 5.7 9.6 8.7 14.7 0.9 2 1.9 2.2 2.5 0.6 0.2-0.6 0.4-8.6 0.5-17.6 0-9.1 0-11.7 0.4-17.5 0.6-8.1 1.7-16.2 3.2-24.3 2.2-11.9 5-23.8 8.5-35.4 2.9-9.4 6.2-18.4 10.3-27.6 3.6-8.4 10-21 13.9-27.1 3.6-5.7 7.2-12.3 11.6-17.9 4.3-6.2 9.2-12.1 14.1-17.9 1.4-1.6 10.9-12.3 14.6-16.4 4-4.4 8.1-9.4 11.9-14.1 3-3.8 3.1-3.9 2.9-6.1-0.1-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3-1.3-1.5-1.7-3.5-2.6-5.3-2.2-4.5-3-6.5-6.8-13.6-1.7-3.1-2-3.4-3.4-3.6-1.6-0.1-4.5 0.5-10.1 4.7-5.2 3.8-10.3 8.3-15.2 12.7-4.3 3.4-12.6 11.7-18.3 18.2-6.9 8-13.1 16.7-18.9 25.6-4.8 7.3-9 15.5-13.1 24-3.9 8.8-7.5 17.8-10.5 27-2.1 6.4-3.8 13-5.2 19.7-1.3 6-2.4 11.6-3.2 18.3-0.5 4-1.1 8.2-1.2 9.3-0.1 1.1-0.4 1.9-0.6 1.9-0.6 0-0.7-6-0.4-19.4 0.3-12.6 1.1-18.5 2.7-27.6 1.1-6.2 2.8-12.3 4.8-18.3 3-8.9 6.6-17.6 10.7-26 3-6.1 6.4-11.9 10.1-17.6 5.9-8.9 12.4-17.6 19.4-25.7 7.1-8.1 19.2-19.7 22.9-22.8 4.7-4 8.5-7.2 12.9-10.6 4.1-3.2 4.7-4 4.7-5.5 0-0.7-1.3-3.7-3.5-7.9-0.3-0.6-0.9-2-1.3-3-0.4-1-1.1-2.9-1.7-4.3-0.6-1.4-1.4-3.7-1.8-5.2-0.6-2.1-1.1-2.9-2-3.4-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1-0.4zm265.4 0c-0.3 0-0.6 0.1-1 0.4-0.9 0.5-1.4 1.4-2 3.4-0.4 1.5-1.2 3.9-1.8 5.2-0.6 1.4-1.3 3.3-1.7 4.3-0.4 1-0.9 2.3-1.3 3-2.1 4.2-3.5 7.2-3.5 7.9 0 1.5 0.6 2.3 4.7 5.5 4.3 3.4 8.2 6.6 12.9 10.6 3.7 3.1 15.8 14.7 22.9 22.8 7 8.1 13.5 16.7 19.4 25.7 3.7 5.6 7.1 11.5 10.1 17.6 4.1 8.4 7.7 17.2 10.7 26 2 6 3.7 12.1 4.8 18.3 1.6 9.1 2.4 15 2.7 27.6 0.3 13.4 0.2 19.4-0.4 19.4-0.2 0-0.5-0.9-0.6-1.9-0.1-1.1-0.7-5.2-1.2-9.3-0.9-6.7-1.9-12.2-3.2-18.3-1.5-6.6-3.1-13.2-5.2-19.6-3-9.2-6.6-18.2-10.5-27-4.1-8.5-8.2-16.7-13.1-24-5.9-8.8-12-17.6-18.9-25.6-5.6-6.5-14-14.8-18.3-18.2-4.8-4.3-10-8.9-15.2-12.7-5.7-4.1-8.6-4.8-10.1-4.7-1.4 0.1-1.7 0.4-3.4 3.6-3.8 7.1-4.5 9-6.8 13.6-0.9 1.7-1.3 3.8-2.6 5.3-0.4 0.5-0.8 1.8-0.9 3-0.2 2.1-0.1 2.3 2.9 6.1 3.8 4.8 7.9 9.7 11.9 14.1 3.7 4.1 13.2 14.8 14.6 16.4 4.9 5.8 9.7 11.7 14.1 17.9 4.3 5.5 8 12.2 11.6 17.9 3.9 6.1 10.3 18.8 13.9 27.1 4 9.2 7.4 18.2 10.3 27.6 3.5 11.6 6.3 23.5 8.5 35.4 1.5 8 2.6 16.1 3.2 24.3 0.5 5.8 0.4 8.4 0.4 17.5 0 9.1 0.2 17 0.5 17.7 0.6 1.6 1.6 1.4 2.5-0.6 3-5.1 5.5-9.7 8.7-14.7 2.8-4.4 10.6-19.1 15.1-29 4.3-9.6 8.2-19.4 11.4-29.4 2.7-8.4 5-17 6.4-25.7 2-11.5 3.2-23.2 3.3-34.9 0-8.3-0.7-16.6-2.3-24.7-1.5-8-3.7-15.9-6.7-23.4-3-7.7-6.9-15.1-11.3-22.1-3.4-5.5-7.4-10.7-11.7-15.5-7.8-8.7-16.8-16.2-25.5-23.9-7.7-6.8-15.8-13.3-23.8-19.9-5.8-4.8-13.1-10.9-17.5-14.3-1.5-1.2-3.7-3.1-4.8-4.1-1.2-1.2-1.7-1.6-2.2-1.6zm-183.4 42c-0.9 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 3.3 0.2 2.7 0.7 4.1 2.6 7.9 1.6 3.1 2.8 5 4 5.9 1.9 1.5 10.2 5.7 16.8 8.5 8.7 3.6 10.1 4.2 16.2 7.2 3.4 1.7 6.7 3.8 7.7 4.5 1 0.6 1.4 2 1.4 3.4l0.1 9.7 0.2 8.5c0.1 1.2 0.1 2.2-1.2 3.5 0 0-2.3 2.1-3.5 3.1-4.5 3.7-8.7 7.8-13.8 10.5-4.5 2.4-9.4 4.6-14.5 4.9-5 0.3-8.4-0.7-14.6-3.1-2.6-1-5-1.7-5.4-1.6-0.9 0.4-2.5 5.9-2.5 8.9 0 5.3 2.5 10.9 6.3 14.5 1.4 1.4 3 2.4 3.5 2.4 0.7 0 4.8-4.8 7.4-6.9 5.7-4.4 11.4-9 18.1-11.6 7.1-2.8 14.1-4.1 22.5-4 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 8.5-0.1 15.4 1.2 22.5 4 6.7 2.6 12.4 7.2 18.1 11.6 2.7 2.1 6.8 6.9 7.4 6.9 0.6 0 2.1-1 3.5-2.4 3.8-3.6 6.3-9.3 6.3-14.5 0-3-1.6-8.6-2.5-8.9-0.4-0.1-2.8 0.6-5.4 1.6-6.2 2.4-9.6 3.4-14.6 3.1-5.1-0.3-10-2.5-14.5-4.9-5.1-2.7-9.3-6.8-13.8-10.5-1.2-1-3.5-3.1-3.5-3.1-1.2-1.3-1.2-2.2-1.2-3.5l0.2-8.5 0.1-9.7c0-1.4 0.4-2.7 1.4-3.4 1-0.6 4.3-2.8 7.7-4.5 6.1-3 7.5-3.6 16.2-7.2 6.6-2.8 14.9-6.9 16.8-8.5 1.1-0.9 2.4-2.8 4-5.9 1.9-3.8 2.4-5.2 2.6-7.9 0.3-3.1 0.2-3.3-0.7-3.3-0.5 0-2.4 1.3-4.2 2.8-1.8 1.6-4.4 3.4-5.9 4-2.5 1.1-3.1 1.2-10.2 1.2-6.3 0-7.7 0.1-8.7 0.8-2.9 1.9-10 4.4-14.5 5.1-2.9 0.5-5.1 0.7-7.3 0.7-2.2 0-4.4-0.2-7.3-0.7-4.5-0.7-11.6-3.2-14.5-5.1-1-0.7-2.4-0.8-8.7-0.8-7.1 0-7.7-0.1-10.2-1.2-1.5-0.6-4.1-2.4-5.9-4-1.8-1.6-3.6-2.8-4.2-2.8zm-29.3 10.1c-1.7 0-1.9 1.9 0.4 5.2 3 4.3 5.2 6.3 8.3 8.8 3.3 2.6 7 5.1 11 6.4 3.3 1.1 6.9 1 10.4 1.1 2.6 0 7.7-0.4 7.9-0.7 0.6-1-1-2-2.4-2.3-3.2-0.6-10.4-2-15.2-4.2-4.7-2.1-9.5-5.3-12.8-8.6-3.3-3.2-6.1-5.8-7.7-5.8zm-7.1 3.8c-0.3 0-0.6 0.2-0.9 0.5-0.6 0.6-0.5 1.2 1.3 5.2 3.3 7.6 6.9 13.1 12.3 17.9 3.5 3.1 8 5.4 12.6 6.5 5.4 1.3 10.1 0.6 16.7-0.3 4.7-0.6 10-1.4 15.1-1.4 4.2 0 11.6 1.3 12.6 1.3 1.7 0.1 1.8 0 2-1.1 0.1-1.2-1.3-2.4-5.7-4.8-5.2-2.8-12.2-3.5-20.4-2-5.9 1-14.8 1.3-18.1 0.6-8.6-2-14.6-6.7-23.1-18.2-2.2-3-3.3-4.2-4.3-4.1zm-7.5 23.2c-0.6 0-1.5 1.1-3.1 3-1.4 1.7-4.5 5.4-7.1 8.3-8.4 9.6-18.6 21.7-25.8 34.7-5 8.6-11.2 21.1-13 26-2.5 6.8-5.6 13.4-7.6 20.8-3.6 11.4-6.9 25-8.7 37.7-2.3 16.8-2.4 34.6-2.3 50.9 0.9 9.5 1.6 19.2 3.8 28.6 3.1 13.1 6.4 25.7 13 38.3 2.2 3.5 4.9 8.1 7.9 11.7 2.3 2.8 3.7 3.7 4.4 2.6 0.3-0.4-0.4-3.6-1.4-6.7-0.9-2.8-1.1-6-1.9-8.9-0.8-3.3-1.8-12.1-2.5-22.1-0.6-9 0.5-26.1 2.4-35 1.5-7.2 2.2-15.6 4.6-23.1 4-18.1 11.4-36.3 19.2-53 4.4-9.2 10.1-19.8 15.6-29.3 6.5-10.9 14.4-23.2 22.1-34 2-2.9 4.2-5.6 5.8-8.6-3.9-2.9-7.9-5.8-11.2-8.3-4.3-3.4-8-8.1-9.9-12.5-1.1-2.5-1.6-5.1-2.9-15.3-0.5-4.1-0.8-5.9-1.6-5.9zm189.3 0c-0.8 0-1 1.8-1.6 5.9-1.3 10.2-1.8 12.8-2.9 15.3-1.9 4.4-5.6 9.1-9.9 12.5-3.3 2.6-7.3 5.5-11.1 8.3 1.6 3 3.8 5.6 5.8 8.6 7.7 10.9 15.6 23.1 22.1 34 5.6 9.6 11.3 20.1 15.6 29.3 7.8 16.8 15.2 35 19.2 53 2.4 7.4 3.1 15.9 4.6 23.1 1.9 9 3 26.1 2.4 35-0.7 10-1.7 18.8-2.5 22.1-0.8 2.9-1 6-1.9 8.9-1 3.1-1.6 6.2-1.4 6.7 0.6 1 2.1 0.2 4.4-2.6 3-3.5 5.6-8.1 7.9-11.7 6.6-12.6 10-25.2 13-38.3 2.2-9.4 2.9-19.1 3.8-28.6 0-16.3 0-34.1-2.3-50.9-1.7-12.8-5.1-26.3-8.7-37.7-2-7.4-5-14-7.6-20.8-1.8-4.9-8-17.4-13-26-7.2-13-17.4-25.1-25.8-34.7-2.5-2.9-5.7-6.6-7.1-8.3-1.6-1.9-2.5-3-3.1-3zm-63.7 16.3c-1.4 0-2 0.6-2 1.8 0 1.3 11.5 6.3 16 6.9 3.8 0.6 7.7-0.2 12.3-2.2 5.8-2.6 7.3-3.6 7.3-4.9 0-1.6-0.8-1.6-5.2-0.3-3.3 1-5 1.2-9.3 1.2-6.7 0-12-0.6-15.8-1.8-1.3-0.4-2.4-0.6-3.2-0.6zm-98.6 49.1c-0.1 0-0.2 0.1-0.3 0.2-0.2 0.2-5.2 8.6-11.2 18.7-15.5 26.2-18.7 33.9-25.4 51.9-4.1 11.1-7.6 22.7-8.9 34.4-2.1 19.2-2.1 39.1 2.1 58 3.7 16.8 6.6 27 20.2 47.5 3.4 5.1 5.4 7.4 8.7 10.7 0.3 0.3 0.7 0.6 1.2 0.6 1.5 0 1-1 0.8-2.4-1.2-9.9-1.7-34.9-1.2-57.9 0.5-22.1 2.2-45.4 5.2-67.9 1.9-13.9 4.9-27.6 8.1-41.4 1.8-6.9 5.8-21.1 9.4-32.7 1.3-4.4 1.4-4.1-3-11.9-3.5-6.1-4.8-8.1-5.7-7.9zm135.2 0c-0.9 0.1-2.3 2.2-5.5 7.9-4.4 7.8-4.3 7.5-3 11.9 3.6 11.6 7.6 25.7 9.4 32.7 3.2 13.7 6.2 27.4 8.1 41.4 3 22.5 4.7 45.8 5.2 67.9 0.5 23.1 0 48.1-1.2 57.9-0.2 1.4-0.6 2.4 0.8 2.4 0.4 0 0.9-0.3 1.2-0.6 3.3-3.3 5.3-5.6 8.7-10.7 13.6-20.5 16.5-30.7 20.2-47.5 4.2-18.9 4.2-38.8 2.1-58-1.3-11.8-4.8-23.3-8.9-34.4-6.7-18.1-9.8-25.7-25.4-51.9-5.9-10.1-11-18.4-11.2-18.7-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2zm-109 24.6c-0.3 0-0.7 0.7-1.1 1.5-3.7 8.4-5.8 16.7-7.8 25.3-2.3 9.8-3.6 19.9-4.9 30-0.9 7.1-0.8 5.3-1.9 21.4-0.7 10.4-0.6 14.4 0.6 26 0.9 8.9 1.5 11.7 2.9 17.4 1.6 6.5 3.2 12.9 6.5 19 4.5 8.7 11.7 16.9 19.9 22.6 1.8 1.3 3.7 2.3 4.3 2.3 1.3 0 1.6-0.8 0.9-2.7-0.5-1-0.8-1.9-1.2-2.8-2.7-7.8-4.6-15.8-6.6-23.7-1.6-6.4-2.9-12.8-4.2-19.2-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.2-3.2-18.3-1-7.1-2-14.1-2.5-21.2-0.8-12.3-1.3-27.1-1.5-40.4-0.1-11.6 0-22.1 0.5-28.8 0.4-5.9 0.2-8.2-0.8-8.2zm83 0c-1 0-1.2 2.3-0.8 8.2 0.5 6.8 0.6 17.3 0.5 28.8-0.2 13.3-0.7 28.1-1.5 40.4-0.5 7.1-1.4 14.2-2.5 21.2-0.9 6.1-2 12.2-3.2 18.3-1.3 6.4-2.6 12.8-4.2 19.2-2 8-3.9 16-6.6 23.7-0.3 1-0.7 1.8-1.2 2.8-0.7 1.8-0.4 2.7 0.9 2.7 0.5 0 2.5-1 4.3-2.3 8.3-5.8 15.5-14 19.9-22.6 3.3-6.1 4.9-12.5 6.5-19 1.4-5.7 2-8.5 2.9-17.4 1.2-11.6 1.3-15.6 0.6-26-1.1-16.1-1-14.3-1.9-21.4-1.3-10-2.5-20.1-4.9-30-2-8.6-4.1-16.9-7.8-25.3-0.3-0.8-0.8-1.5-1.1-1.5zm-44.1 5.9c-13.8 0-14.7 0.1-15.2 0.9-0.7 1 0.2 15.1 0.5 22.7 0.3 8 0.9 16.1 1.4 24.1 0.6 8.7 1.2 17.3 2.2 26 0.8 7.4 1.4 14.8 3.1 22 1.5 6.7 3.8 13.2 6.3 19.6 1.2 3.1 3.3 8.3 4.3 9.1 1-0.9 3.1-6 4.3-9.1 2.5-6.4 4.8-12.9 6.3-19.6 1.7-7.2 2.3-14.6 3.1-22 1-8.6 1.5-17.3 2.2-26 0.6-8 1.1-16.1 1.4-24.1 0.3-7.6 1.2-21.7 0.5-22.7-0.5-0.8-1.4-0.8-15.2-0.9-1.3 0.1-2 0.1-2.6 0.1-0.7 0-1.3 0-2.6-0.1z">
 
 </path>
    </g>
  
</svg>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Вопрос удалось решить с помощью подключения `jQuery`
Расширенные комментарии, как это делается  в коде программы.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Переменная для 'stroke-dashoffset' 
  var $dashOffset = $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset");
  //на событие прокрутки - выполнить функцию
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //рассчитать, как далеко вниз по прокручена страница 
    var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height())) * 100);
    //преобразовать значение в пикселях dashoffset в целое число
    var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);
    //получить значение, которое будет вычтено из 'stroke-dashoffset'
    var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);
    //установить новое значение dashoffset, чтобы создать эффект рисования
    $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
font-family:sans-serif;
background: rgb(34,193,195);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  letter-spacing: .09em;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke:black;
  fill:none;
  stroke-width:4;  
}

.Lion {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Нарисуйте голову льва при прокрутке</h1>
<div class="Lion"></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
   <g> 
            
       <path class="path"  d="m272.2 113.6c-0.3 0-0.6 0-0.9 0.1-0.7 0.1 2.2 2.5 10.9 11.2 9.8 9.7 18.2 19.1 23 25.5 5.9 8.1 12.3 18.6 16.4 29.1 0.8 1.6 3.6 11.9 4.6 16.9 0.5 2.8 1 5.4 1.2 5.8 0.8 2.5 3.9-8.4 4.8-13 1.2-5.6 1.2-11.4 1-17.1-0.2-5.8-0.5-11.8-2.2-17.4-1.4-4.8-3.6-9.4-6.7-13.3-6.6-8.2-15.1-15.1-24.4-20.1-6.4-3.5-13.8-4.9-20.9-6.5-2.2-0.5-4.8-1.3-6.9-1.2zm194.7 0c-2.1 0-4.7 0.7-6.9 1.2-7.1 1.6-14.5 3.1-20.9 6.5-9.3 5-17.8 11.8-24.4 20.1-3.1 3.9-5.3 8.6-6.7 13.3-1.7 5.6-2 11.5-2.2 17.4-0.2 5.7-0.1 11.5 1 17.1 1 4.5 4 15.4 4.8 13 0.1-0.3 0.6-2.9 1.2-5.8 0.9-5 3.7-15.3 4.6-16.9 4.2-10.5 10.5-21 16.5-29.1 4.8-6.5 13.2-15.8 23-25.5 8.7-8.7 11.6-11.1 10.9-11.2-0.3 0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.1zm-97.3 24.5c-0.8-0.1-1.4 5.7-2 8.5-0.9 4.3-1.3 8.7-2.4 12.9-1.8 6.9-4.3 13.7-7.1 20.3-2.4 5.7-6.4 13.4-8.3 16.5-5.5 8.8-9 13.7-13.9 19.6-6.1 7.3-7.4 8.8-13 14.4-10.8 10.8-19.3 15.7-30 22.1-7.3 4.4-15.3 7.6-23.1 11-17.5 7.6-36.3 14.2-55.9 20.5-12.8 4.3-26.1 7.4-38.3 13.1-18.2 8.6-36.3 18.5-51.6 31.6-11.5 9.9-21.1 22.1-29.5 34.7-5.1 7.7-9 15.2-12.6 24.7-3 6.3-4.8 12.7-6.7 19.3-1.5 5.2-3 9.8-3.6 15.7-0.3 1.9-0.8 4.5-1.1 5.7-0.9 3.4-1.3 7.6-0.7 9 0.3 1.3 1.9 1.5 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.7-1.8 1.5-3.1 1.8-2.9 4.4-7 6.9-10.3 9.6-12.2 19.7-24.2 31.5-34.2 14.4-12.3 30.6-22.3 47.2-31.4 18.1-10 36.9-17 56.7-25.4 7.8-3.4 14.4-5.6 23.2-10.3 2.6-1.8 3.7-1.2 2.7 1.4-0.4 0.9-0.7 2.7-0.8 4-0.2 3 0.6 3.7 2.9 2.8 1.8-0.7 2.7-1 7.8-2.6 2.2-0.7 4.1-1.5 4.3-1.9 0.3-0.7-3.8-5-7.9-8.4-2.3-1.9-4.7-4.8-4.3-5.2 0.1-0.1 2 0 3.1 0.1 2.4 0.3 2.9 0.3 10.1 0.5 11.4 0.4 11.6 0.6 10-3.5-1.3-3.3-2.6-6.3-3.9-9.7-0.7-1.3-1.1-2.5-0.9-2.7 0.2-0.2 3.6-0.5 7.9-0.5 4.2 0 8.8-0.2 10.2-0.4l2.5-0.4c1-1-0.1-4.6-0.4-6.9-0.2-1.7-0.8-3.8-1-5.2s-0.4-3.3-0.5-4.2c-0.2-1 0-1.7 0.4-1.9 0.5-0.2 1.4-0.1 2.7 0.5 1.1 0.5 3.2 1.3 4.7 1.9 1.5 0.5 3.8 1.4 5 1.9 2.7 1 4.1 1.1 4.6 0.3 0.5-0.7 1.5-3.4 1.9-5.1 1.4-5.1 11-19.2 13.7-20.1 0.8-0.2 3.4 1.4 4.6 2.4 0.4 0.4 7.6 6 9.2 7.1 1.5 0.9 2.6 0.8 3-0.5 0.1-0.4 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.6 1.8-3.9 3.7-7.2 6.6-14 0.6-2.6 1.5-1.9 5.2 4.1 5.3 8.4 12.5 15.8 21.2 21.6 3.3 2.2 2.6 1.8 4.3 2.7 1.7-0.9 1-0.5 4.3-2.7 8.7-5.8 16-13.2 21.2-21.6 3.8-6 4.7-6.7 5.2-4.1 2.9 6.7 4.8 10.1 6.6 14 0.5 1 1 2.2 1.1 2.6 0.4 1.2 1.5 1.4 3 0.5 1.6-1 8.8-6.7 9.2-7.1 1.2-1.1 3.8-2.7 4.6-2.4 2.7 0.9 12.4 15 13.7 20.1 0.5 1.8 1.5 4.4 1.9 5.1 0.5 0.8 2 0.7 4.6-0.3 1.3-0.5 3.5-1.3 5-1.9 1.5-0.5 3.6-1.4 4.7-1.9 1.3-0.6 2.2-0.8 2.7-0.5 0.5 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.9-0.1 0.9-0.4 2.8-0.5 4.2-0.2 1.4-0.7 3.4-1 5.2-0.3 2.3-1.3 5.9-0.4 6.9l2.5 0.4c1.4 0.2 6 0.4 10.2 0.4 4.3 0 7.8 0.2 7.9 0.5 0.1 0.2-0.3 1.5-0.9 2.7-1.4 3.3-2.7 6.4-3.9 9.7-1.6 4.1-1.4 3.8 10 3.5 7.2-0.2 7.8-0.2 10.1-0.5 1.1-0.1 3-0.2 3.1-0.1 0.4 0.4-1.9 3.2-4.3 5.2-4.1 3.4-8.1 7.7-7.9 8.4 0.1 0.4 2.1 1.2 4.3 1.9 5.1 1.6 6 1.9 7.8 2.6 2.3 0.9 3.1 0.2 2.9-2.8-0.1-1.3-0.4-3.1-0.8-4-1.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 2.7-1.4 8.8 4.8 15.5 7 23.2 10.3 19.9 8.4 38.6 15.4 56.7 25.4 16.5 9.1 32.8 19.1 47.2 31.4 11.8 10.1 21.9 22.1 31.5 34.2 2.6 3.2 5.2 7.3 6.9 10.3 0.8 1.3 1 1.7 1.5 3.1 0.4 1.5 2 1.3 2.4 0 0.5-1.4 0.2-5.6-0.7-9-0.3-1.3-0.8-3.8-1.1-5.7-0.6-5.9-2.1-10.5-3.6-15.7-1.9-6.5-3.7-13-6.7-19.3-3.6-9.4-7.4-17-12.6-24.7-8.4-12.6-17.9-24.8-29.5-34.7-15.3-13.1-33.4-23-51.6-31.6-12.2-5.7-25.5-8.8-38.3-13.1-19.6-6.4-38.4-12.9-55.9-20.5-7.8-3.4-15.8-6.6-23.1-11-10.6-6.4-19.1-11.2-30-22.1-5.6-5.6-7-7.1-13-14.4-4.9-5.9-8.4-10.8-13.9-19.6-1.9-3.1-5.9-10.8-8.3-16.5-2.8-6.6-5.3-13.4-7.1-20.3-1.1-4.2-1.5-8.6-2.4-12.9-0.6-2.9-1.2-8.6-2-8.5zm-120.2 11.9c-4.1 0-8.1 0.5-12 1.5-10.1 2.7-17.7 8-27.5 15.2-2.3 1.7-3.5 3.1-2.6 3.6 0.4 0.2 8.4-1.8 13.8-2.1 10.7-0.5 21.5 1.6 31.8 4.4 10.7 2.9 20.8 7.9 30.8 12.8 5.7 2.8 10.1 5.5 16.5 9.3 4.9 2.9 4.9 1.3 1.3-4-2.1-3.2-4.2-7.2-6.7-10.6-3.9-5.3-7.7-10.7-12.6-14.9-6.9-5.9-14.7-11.6-23.5-14-3-0.8-6.1-1.2-9.3-1.2zm240.4 0c-3.2 0-6.3 0.4-9.3 1.2-8.8 2.4-16.5 8.1-23.5 14-5 4.2-8.8 9.7-12.6 14.9-2.5 3.4-4.6 7.4-6.7 10.6-3.6 5.3-3.6 6.8 1.3 4 6.5-3.8 10.9-6.5 16.5-9.3 10-4.8 20-9.9 30.8-12.8 10.3-2.8 21.1-4.9 31.8-4.4 5.4 0.3 13.5 2.3 13.8 2.1 0.9-0.6-0.3-2-2.6-3.6-9.8-7.3-17.4-12.5-27.5-15.2-3.9-1-8-1.6-12-1.5zm-263.5 27.1c-7.5 0.1-14.8 2.1-22.2 5-2.8 1.1-12 6.4-14.9 8.6-8 6.1-15.3 13.1-24.4 23.2-7.8 8.7-8.9 10.1-8.9 11.1 0 0.8 2.3 0.5 5.1-0.7 6.1-2.7 13.7-5.8 20.7-8.1 7-2.3 14-4.6 21.2-5.7 7.8-1.2 15.9-1.8 23.8-1.2 8.8 0.7 17.1 4.5 25.9 5.4 10.8 1.1 21.9 1.4 32.6-0.3 5.5-0.8 10.8-3 16-4.9 2.9-1 7.7-3.1 8.5-3.4 1.9-0.7 2.6-1.4 2.3-2.2-0.2-0.5-1.7-0.7-5.9-0.9-9.2-0.5-20.5-3.8-30.3-7.3-5.6-2-10.9-5.1-16.2-7.8-10.8-5.5-19.4-10.7-31.8-10.9-0.5 0-1 0-1.5 0zm285.2 0c-12.4 0.2-20.9 5.4-31.8 10.9-5.4 2.7-10.5 5.8-16.2 7.8-9.8 3.5-21.1 6.8-30.3 7.3-4.2 0.2-5.7 0.4-5.9 0.9-0.3 0.8 0.4 1.5 2.3 2.2 0.8 0.3 5.6 2.4 8.5 3.4 5.3 1.8 10.5 4 16 4.9 10.7 1.6 21.8 1.3 32.6 0.3 8.8-0.9 17.1-4.7 25.9-5.4 7.9-0.6 15.9 0 23.8 1.2 7.2 1.1 14.3 3.4 21.2 5.7 7.1 2.3 14.6 5.4 20.7 8.1 2.8 1.2 5.1 1.5 5.1 0.7 0-1-1.1-2.4-9-11.1-9.1-10.2-16.4-17.1-24.4-23.2-2.9-2.2-12.1-7.5-14.9-8.6-7.9-3.1-15.7-5.1-23.8-5zm-188.9 30.7c-0.8 0.1-2.8 1.5-7 4.8-5.6 4.5-10.1 7-16.2 9.1-7.9 2.7-14 4.1-21.2 5.1-8.7 1.2-17.5 1-26.3 1.1-6.8 0.1-13.6-0.1-20.3-0.2-12.3-0.2-23.9-1.1-37-0.8-8.6 0.5-17.3 0.9-25.6 3-8.1 2-16.1 4.9-23.3 9.2-5.5 3.3-10.3 7.8-14.8 12.5-4.3 4.5-8 9.5-11.2 14.7-3.1 5-5.8 10.4-8 15.9-2.4 5.7-4.1 11.7-5.7 17.7-0.5 1.9-0.9 4.2-1.3 5.9-0.4 1.7-1.2 4.3-1 4.8 0.3 0.9 1.7 0.6 3.3-0.4 0.8-0.5 9.5-6.3 14.4-9.2 8.9-5.1 18.1-9.7 27.4-13.9 6.5-2.9 13.1-5.5 19.9-7.8 14.5-4.9 29.3-9 44.2-12.5 7.8-1.9 15.9-2.6 23.7-4.6 11.4-2.9 22.9-5.7 33.6-10.5 11.7-5.3 22.9-11.9 33.1-19.8 4.1-3.2 8.7-7.9 11-10.9 4.9-6.2 6.3-7.9 7.6-9.7 0.8-1.1 1.5-2.4 1.5-2.7 0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.5-0.7zm94.1 0c-0.4 0-0.5 0.2-0.5 0.7 0 0.4 0.7 1.6 1.5 2.7 1.3 1.8 2.6 3.5 7.6 9.7 2.3 2.9 6.9 7.7 11 10.9 10.2 7.9 21.3 14.6 33.1 19.8 10.7 4.8 22.2 7.6 33.6 10.5 7.8 2 15.9 2.7 23.7 4.6 14.9 3.6 29.7 7.6 44.2 12.5 6.7 2.3 13.4 4.9 19.9 7.8 9.4 4.2 18.5 8.8 27.4 13.9 4.9 2.8 13.6 8.6 14.4 9.2 1.5 1 3 1.3 3.3 0.4 0.1-0.5-0.6-3.1-1-4.8-0.4-1.7-0.8-4-1.3-5.9-1.6-6-3.4-11.9-5.7-17.6-2.3-5.5-4.9-10.8-8-15.9-3.3-5.2-7-10.2-11.3-14.7-4.4-4.7-9.2-9.2-14.8-12.5-7.2-4.3-15.2-7.2-23.3-9.2-8.3-2.1-17-2.5-25.6-3-13.1-0.2-24.7 0.6-37 0.8-6.8 0.1-13.6 0.3-20.3 0.2-8.8-0.1-17.6 0.1-26.3-1.1-7.2-1-13.4-2.4-21.2-5.1-6.1-2.1-10.6-4.6-16.2-9.1-4.2-3.3-6.2-4.8-7-4.8zm-124.5 123.7-5.4 3.6c-3 2-7.9 5.1-10.9 6.8-10.8 6.3-11.8 7-12.2 7.6-0.5 1 1.2 2.9 3.7 4l2.1 0.9 3.7-1.5c2-0.8 4.4-1.5 5.2-1.5 1.4 0 1.6 0.1 2.1 1.8 0.3 1 0.7 2.6 0.9 3.6 0.4 2.4 2.2 3.9 7.3 6.4 6.8 3.3 9.6 4 16.7 4.2 8.9 0.3 8.2-0.1 8.2 4.4 0 2.1-0.3 4.8-0.7 6-0.8 2.6-0.9 4.3-0.3 4.3 0.6 0 4.5-1.7 6.1-2.6 2.6-1.5 2.7-1 2.5 7.5-0.3 11.5-1.5 17.1-8 37.1-2.1 6.7-4.2 13.1-4.6 14.3-0.4 1.2-0.6 2.5-0.4 2.9 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.7 0.6 0.7 1.2 0 13.5-30.8 17.4-43.4 1.9-6.2 3.8-17.7 3.8-23.4 0-1.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-2.7 0.6-0.7 0.7-1.1 0.2-2.8-0.3-1.1-0.8-4.9-1.2-8.4-0.8-7.8-2-11.6-4.3-14-2.2-2.3-7.3-4.4-13-5.3-4.9-0.8-6.3-1.5-6.3-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.3-0.6-1.6-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.1-6.8 4.7-3.6 3.2-5 3.7-5.3 1.8-0.1-0.8 0.6-1.4 3.1-3.2 3.2-2.1 4.6-3.5 4.6-4.6 0-0.3-2-1.4-4.5-2.5l-4.5-2zm155.6 0-4.5 2c-2.5 1.1-4.5 2.2-4.5 2.5 0 1 1.4 2.4 4.6 4.6 2.6 1.7 3.2 2.4 3.1 3.2-0.3 1.9-1.7 1.4-5.3-1.8-5.3-4.7-6-5.3-6.8-4.7-0.3 0.3-0.6 1-0.6 1.6 0 2-1.4 2.7-6.3 3.5-5.7 0.9-10.8 2.9-13 5.3-2.3 2.4-3.5 6.2-4.3 14-0.4 3.5-0.9 7.3-1.2 8.4-0.4 1.7-0.4 2.1 0.2 2.8 0.4 0.5 0.7 1.6 0.7 2.7 0 3.3 0.9 11.1 1.9 15.9 1.4 6.7 2.4 10 7.8 24.4 4.1 10.8 4.7 12.5 8.1 20 1.6 3.6 3.1 6.5 3.3 6.5 0.8 0 0.9-1.4 0.2-3.5-0.4-1.2-2.4-7.6-4.6-14.3-6.4-20-7.6-25.6-8-37.1-0.2-8.5-0.1-8.9 2.5-7.5 1.6 0.9 5.6 2.6 6.1 2.6 0.6 0 0.5-1.7-0.3-4.3-0.4-1.2-0.7-3.9-0.7-6 0-4.5-0.7-4.2 8.2-4.4 7-0.2 9.9-0.9 16.7-4.2 5.1-2.5 6.9-4.1 7.3-6.4 0.2-1 0.6-2.6 0.9-3.6 0.5-1.7 0.7-1.8 2.1-1.8 0.9 0 3.2 0.7 5.2 1.5l3.7 1.5 2.1-0.9c2.4-1.1 4.2-3 3.6-4-0.4-0.6-1.4-1.3-12.2-7.6-3-1.8-7.9-4.8-10.9-6.8l-5.4-3.6zm-220.2 8.8c-0.3 0-1.9 0.9-3.6 2.1-4.4 2.9-11.1 5.9-16.7 8.9-9.7 5.2-19.6 9.9-29.1 15.5-9.9 5.8-19.8 11.8-29.2 18.4-8.8 6.2-17.9 12.2-25.4 19.8-9.3 9.5-17.7 20.1-24 31.8-4.6 8.4-7.6 17.5-9.7 27.1-0.9 1.7-3.3 15.1-4.1 22.7-0.8 7.4-0.9 14.8-0.8 22.2 0.2 9.4 1 18.8 2.2 28.1 0.6 5.2 1.7 10.4 2.7 15.5 0.8 4.2 1.7 8.4 2.6 12.6 0.2 1.1 0.5 3 0.8 3.3 0.7 0.9 2.2 0.7 2.6-0.5 0.2-0.6 0.6-2.9 0.9-5.1 0.3-2.2 0.7-3.7 1.1-5.5 0.9-3.5 1.9-7.1 3-10.5 1.6-5 3.4-10.1 5.5-14.9 3.4-7.7 7.5-15.2 11.8-22.5 2.8-4.7 5.8-9.3 9-13.8 4.3-6 8.8-11.8 13.7-17.4 8.4-9.6 17.4-18.7 26.8-27.3 11-10.1 23.1-19 34.7-28.4 6.7-5.4 13.6-10.7 20.3-16.1 7.1-5.7 12-10.4 15.2-14.8 3.6-4.9 7-12.7 7.3-17.1 0.2-2.5 0.1-2.8-1.4-4.3-4.6-5-7.3-10.2-10.5-16.5-2.1-4.4-3-7-3.3-9-0.3-1.9-1.7-4.2-2.6-4.2zm284.3 0c-0.9 0-2.3 2.3-2.6 4.2-0.3 2-1.3 4.6-3.3 9-3.2 6.3-6 11.5-10.5 16.5-1.5 1.6-1.6 1.8-1.4 4.3 0.3 4.4 3.7 12.2 7.3 17.1 3.2 4.3 8.1 9.1 15.2 14.8 6.7 5.4 13.6 10.7 20.3 16.1 11.6 9.4 23.7 18.3 34.7 28.4 9.4 8.6 18.3 17.8 26.8 27.3 4.9 5.5 9.4 11.4 13.7 17.4 3.2 4.5 6.2 9.1 9 13.8 4.3 7.3 8.3 14.7 11.8 22.5 2.2 4.8 3.9 9.9 5.5 14.9 1.1 3.5 2.1 7 3 10.5 0.4 1.8 0.8 3.2 1.1 5.5 0.3 2.2 0.7 4.5 0.9 5.1 0.4 1.1 1.8 1.4 2.6 0.5 0.3-0.3 0.5-2.2 0.8-3.3 0.9-4.2 1.8-8.4 2.6-12.6 1-5.2 2-10.3 2.7-15.5 1.2-9.3 1.9-18.7 2.1-28.1 0.2-7.4 0-14.8-0.8-22.2-0.8-7.6-3.2-21-4.1-22.7-2.1-9.6-5.1-18.7-9.7-27.1-6.3-11.7-14.7-22.3-24-31.8-7.5-7.7-16.6-13.6-25.4-19.8-9.4-6.6-19.2-12.6-29.2-18.4-9.5-5.5-19.4-10.3-29.1-15.5-5.6-3-12.2-6-16.7-8.9-1.7-1.1-3.3-2.1-3.6-2.1zm-274.8 74.1c-0.5 0-1 0.5-2.2 1.6-1.1 1-3.2 2.9-4.8 4.1-4.4 3.5-11.7 9.5-17.5 14.3-8 6.6-16 13-23.8 19.9-8.7 7.7-17.7 15.3-25.5 23.9-4.3 4.8-8.2 10-11.7 15.5-4.4 7-8.2 14.4-11.3 22.1-3 7.6-5.2 15.4-6.7 23.4-1.5 8.1-2.3 16.4-2.3 24.7 0 11.7 1.3 23.4 3.3 34.9 1.5 8.7 3.8 17.3 6.4 25.7 3.2 10 7.1 19.8 11.4 29.4 4.5 9.9 12.2 24.6 15.1 29 3.2 5.1 5.7 9.6 8.7 14.7 0.9 2 1.9 2.2 2.5 0.6 0.2-0.6 0.4-8.6 0.5-17.6 0-9.1 0-11.7 0.4-17.5 0.6-8.1 1.7-16.2 3.2-24.3 2.2-11.9 5-23.8 8.5-35.4 2.9-9.4 6.2-18.4 10.3-27.6 3.6-8.4 10-21 13.9-27.1 3.6-5.7 7.2-12.3 11.6-17.9 4.3-6.2 9.2-12.1 14.1-17.9 1.4-1.6 10.9-12.3 14.6-16.4 4-4.4 8.1-9.4 11.9-14.1 3-3.8 3.1-3.9 2.9-6.1-0.1-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3-1.3-1.5-1.7-3.5-2.6-5.3-2.2-4.5-3-6.5-6.8-13.6-1.7-3.1-2-3.4-3.4-3.6-1.6-0.1-4.5 0.5-10.1 4.7-5.2 3.8-10.3 8.3-15.2 12.7-4.3 3.4-12.6 11.7-18.3 18.2-6.9 8-13.1 16.7-18.9 25.6-4.8 7.3-9 15.5-13.1 24-3.9 8.8-7.5 17.8-10.5 27-2.1 6.4-3.8 13-5.2 19.7-1.3 6-2.4 11.6-3.2 18.3-0.5 4-1.1 8.2-1.2 9.3-0.1 1.1-0.4 1.9-0.6 1.9-0.6 0-0.7-6-0.4-19.4 0.3-12.6 1.1-18.5 2.7-27.6 1.1-6.2 2.8-12.3 4.8-18.3 3-8.9 6.6-17.6 10.7-26 3-6.1 6.4-11.9 10.1-17.6 5.9-8.9 12.4-17.6 19.4-25.7 7.1-8.1 19.2-19.7 22.9-22.8 4.7-4 8.5-7.2 12.9-10.6 4.1-3.2 4.7-4 4.7-5.5 0-0.7-1.3-3.7-3.5-7.9-0.3-0.6-0.9-2-1.3-3-0.4-1-1.1-2.9-1.7-4.3-0.6-1.4-1.4-3.7-1.8-5.2-0.6-2.1-1.1-2.9-2-3.4-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1-0.4zm265.4 0c-0.3 0-0.6 0.1-1 0.4-0.9 0.5-1.4 1.4-2 3.4-0.4 1.5-1.2 3.9-1.8 5.2-0.6 1.4-1.3 3.3-1.7 4.3-0.4 1-0.9 2.3-1.3 3-2.1 4.2-3.5 7.2-3.5 7.9 0 1.5 0.6 2.3 4.7 5.5 4.3 3.4 8.2 6.6 12.9 10.6 3.7 3.1 15.8 14.7 22.9 22.8 7 8.1 13.5 16.7 19.4 25.7 3.7 5.6 7.1 11.5 10.1 17.6 4.1 8.4 7.7 17.2 10.7 26 2 6 3.7 12.1 4.8 18.3 1.6 9.1 2.4 15 2.7 27.6 0.3 13.4 0.2 19.4-0.4 19.4-0.2 0-0.5-0.9-0.6-1.9-0.1-1.1-0.7-5.2-1.2-9.3-0.9-6.7-1.9-12.2-3.2-18.3-1.5-6.6-3.1-13.2-5.2-19.6-3-9.2-6.6-18.2-10.5-27-4.1-8.5-8.2-16.7-13.1-24-5.9-8.8-12-17.6-18.9-25.6-5.6-6.5-14-14.8-18.3-18.2-4.8-4.3-10-8.9-15.2-12.7-5.7-4.1-8.6-4.8-10.1-4.7-1.4 0.1-1.7 0.4-3.4 3.6-3.8 7.1-4.5 9-6.8 13.6-0.9 1.7-1.3 3.8-2.6 5.3-0.4 0.5-0.8 1.8-0.9 3-0.2 2.1-0.1 2.3 2.9 6.1 3.8 4.8 7.9 9.7 11.9 14.1 3.7 4.1 13.2 14.8 14.6 16.4 4.9 5.8 9.7 11.7 14.1 17.9 4.3 5.5 8 12.2 11.6 17.9 3.9 6.1 10.3 18.8 13.9 27.1 4 9.2 7.4 18.2 10.3 27.6 3.5 11.6 6.3 23.5 8.5 35.4 1.5 8 2.6 16.1 3.2 24.3 0.5 5.8 0.4 8.4 0.4 17.5 0 9.1 0.2 17 0.5 17.7 0.6 1.6 1.6 1.4 2.5-0.6 3-5.1 5.5-9.7 8.7-14.7 2.8-4.4 10.6-19.1 15.1-29 4.3-9.6 8.2-19.4 11.4-29.4 2.7-8.4 5-17 6.4-25.7 2-11.5 3.2-23.2 3.3-34.9 0-8.3-0.7-16.6-2.3-24.7-1.5-8-3.7-15.9-6.7-23.4-3-7.7-6.9-15.1-11.3-22.1-3.4-5.5-7.4-10.7-11.7-15.5-7.8-8.7-16.8-16.2-25.5-23.9-7.7-6.8-15.8-13.3-23.8-19.9-5.8-4.8-13.1-10.9-17.5-14.3-1.5-1.2-3.7-3.1-4.8-4.1-1.2-1.2-1.7-1.6-2.2-1.6zm-183.4 42c-0.9 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 3.3 0.2 2.7 0.7 4.1 2.6 7.9 1.6 3.1 2.8 5 4 5.9 1.9 1.5 10.2 5.7 16.8 8.5 8.7 3.6 10.1 4.2 16.2 7.2 3.4 1.7 6.7 3.8 7.7 4.5 1 0.6 1.4 2 1.4 3.4l0.1 9.7 0.2 8.5c0.1 1.2 0.1 2.2-1.2 3.5 0 0-2.3 2.1-3.5 3.1-4.5 3.7-8.7 7.8-13.8 10.5-4.5 2.4-9.4 4.6-14.5 4.9-5 0.3-8.4-0.7-14.6-3.1-2.6-1-5-1.7-5.4-1.6-0.9 0.4-2.5 5.9-2.5 8.9 0 5.3 2.5 10.9 6.3 14.5 1.4 1.4 3 2.4 3.5 2.4 0.7 0 4.8-4.8 7.4-6.9 5.7-4.4 11.4-9 18.1-11.6 7.1-2.8 14.1-4.1 22.5-4 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 8.5-0.1 15.4 1.2 22.5 4 6.7 2.6 12.4 7.2 18.1 11.6 2.7 2.1 6.8 6.9 7.4 6.9 0.6 0 2.1-1 3.5-2.4 3.8-3.6 6.3-9.3 6.3-14.5 0-3-1.6-8.6-2.5-8.9-0.4-0.1-2.8 0.6-5.4 1.6-6.2 2.4-9.6 3.4-14.6 3.1-5.1-0.3-10-2.5-14.5-4.9-5.1-2.7-9.3-6.8-13.8-10.5-1.2-1-3.5-3.1-3.5-3.1-1.2-1.3-1.2-2.2-1.2-3.5l0.2-8.5 0.1-9.7c0-1.4 0.4-2.7 1.4-3.4 1-0.6 4.3-2.8 7.7-4.5 6.1-3 7.5-3.6 16.2-7.2 6.6-2.8 14.9-6.9 16.8-8.5 1.1-0.9 2.4-2.8 4-5.9 1.9-3.8 2.4-5.2 2.6-7.9 0.3-3.1 0.2-3.3-0.7-3.3-0.5 0-2.4 1.3-4.2 2.8-1.8 1.6-4.4 3.4-5.9 4-2.5 1.1-3.1 1.2-10.2 1.2-6.3 0-7.7 0.1-8.7 0.8-2.9 1.9-10 4.4-14.5 5.1-2.9 0.5-5.1 0.7-7.3 0.7-2.2 0-4.4-0.2-7.3-0.7-4.5-0.7-11.6-3.2-14.5-5.1-1-0.7-2.4-0.8-8.7-0.8-7.1 0-7.7-0.1-10.2-1.2-1.5-0.6-4.1-2.4-5.9-4-1.8-1.6-3.6-2.8-4.2-2.8zm-29.3 10.1c-1.7 0-1.9 1.9 0.4 5.2 3 4.3 5.2 6.3 8.3 8.8 3.3 2.6 7 5.1 11 6.4 3.3 1.1 6.9 1 10.4 1.1 2.6 0 7.7-0.4 7.9-0.7 0.6-1-1-2-2.4-2.3-3.2-0.6-10.4-2-15.2-4.2-4.7-2.1-9.5-5.3-12.8-8.6-3.3-3.2-6.1-5.8-7.7-5.8zm-7.1 3.8c-0.3 0-0.6 0.2-0.9 0.5-0.6 0.6-0.5 1.2 1.3 5.2 3.3 7.6 6.9 13.1 12.3 17.9 3.5 3.1 8 5.4 12.6 6.5 5.4 1.3 10.1 0.6 16.7-0.3 4.7-0.6 10-1.4 15.1-1.4 4.2 0 11.6 1.3 12.6 1.3 1.7 0.1 1.8 0 2-1.1 0.1-1.2-1.3-2.4-5.7-4.8-5.2-2.8-12.2-3.5-20.4-2-5.9 1-14.8 1.3-18.1 0.6-8.6-2-14.6-6.7-23.1-18.2-2.2-3-3.3-4.2-4.3-4.1zm-7.5 23.2c-0.6 0-1.5 1.1-3.1 3-1.4 1.7-4.5 5.4-7.1 8.3-8.4 9.6-18.6 21.7-25.8 34.7-5 8.6-11.2 21.1-13 26-2.5 6.8-5.6 13.4-7.6 20.8-3.6 11.4-6.9 25-8.7 37.7-2.3 16.8-2.4 34.6-2.3 50.9 0.9 9.5 1.6 19.2 3.8 28.6 3.1 13.1 6.4 25.7 13 38.3 2.2 3.5 4.9 8.1 7.9 11.7 2.3 2.8 3.7 3.7 4.4 2.6 0.3-0.4-0.4-3.6-1.4-6.7-0.9-2.8-1.1-6-1.9-8.9-0.8-3.3-1.8-12.1-2.5-22.1-0.6-9 0.5-26.1 2.4-35 1.5-7.2 2.2-15.6 4.6-23.1 4-18.1 11.4-36.3 19.2-53 4.4-9.2 10.1-19.8 15.6-29.3 6.5-10.9 14.4-23.2 22.1-34 2-2.9 4.2-5.6 5.8-8.6-3.9-2.9-7.9-5.8-11.2-8.3-4.3-3.4-8-8.1-9.9-12.5-1.1-2.5-1.6-5.1-2.9-15.3-0.5-4.1-0.8-5.9-1.6-5.9zm189.3 0c-0.8 0-1 1.8-1.6 5.9-1.3 10.2-1.8 12.8-2.9 15.3-1.9 4.4-5.6 9.1-9.9 12.5-3.3 2.6-7.3 5.5-11.1 8.3 1.6 3 3.8 5.6 5.8 8.6 7.7 10.9 15.6 23.1 22.1 34 5.6 9.6 11.3 20.1 15.6 29.3 7.8 16.8 15.2 35 19.2 53 2.4 7.4 3.1 15.9 4.6 23.1 1.9 9 3 26.1 2.4 35-0.7 10-1.7 18.8-2.5 22.1-0.8 2.9-1 6-1.9 8.9-1 3.1-1.6 6.2-1.4 6.7 0.6 1 2.1 0.2 4.4-2.6 3-3.5 5.6-8.1 7.9-11.7 6.6-12.6 10-25.2 13-38.3 2.2-9.4 2.9-19.1 3.8-28.6 0-16.3 0-34.1-2.3-50.9-1.7-12.8-5.1-26.3-8.7-37.7-2-7.4-5-14-7.6-20.8-1.8-4.9-8-17.4-13-26-7.2-13-17.4-25.1-25.8-34.7-2.5-2.9-5.7-6.6-7.1-8.3-1.6-1.9-2.5-3-3.1-3zm-63.7 16.3c-1.4 0-2 0.6-2 1.8 0 1.3 11.5 6.3 16 6.9 3.8 0.6 7.7-0.2 12.3-2.2 5.8-2.6 7.3-3.6 7.3-4.9 0-1.6-0.8-1.6-5.2-0.3-3.3 1-5 1.2-9.3 1.2-6.7 0-12-0.6-15.8-1.8-1.3-0.4-2.4-0.6-3.2-0.6zm-98.6 49.1c-0.1 0-0.2 0.1-0.3 0.2-0.2 0.2-5.2 8.6-11.2 18.7-15.5 26.2-18.7 33.9-25.4 51.9-4.1 11.1-7.6 22.7-8.9 34.4-2.1 19.2-2.1 39.1 2.1 58 3.7 16.8 6.6 27 20.2 47.5 3.4 5.1 5.4 7.4 8.7 10.7 0.3 0.3 0.7 0.6 1.2 0.6 1.5 0 1-1 0.8-2.4-1.2-9.9-1.7-34.9-1.2-57.9 0.5-22.1 2.2-45.4 5.2-67.9 1.9-13.9 4.9-27.6 8.1-41.4 1.8-6.9 5.8-21.1 9.4-32.7 1.3-4.4 1.4-4.1-3-11.9-3.5-6.1-4.8-8.1-5.7-7.9zm135.2 0c-0.9 0.1-2.3 2.2-5.5 7.9-4.4 7.8-4.3 7.5-3 11.9 3.6 11.6 7.6 25.7 9.4 32.7 3.2 13.7 6.2 27.4 8.1 41.4 3 22.5 4.7 45.8 5.2 67.9 0.5 23.1 0 48.1-1.2 57.9-0.2 1.4-0.6 2.4 0.8 2.4 0.4 0 0.9-0.3 1.2-0.6 3.3-3.3 5.3-5.6 8.7-10.7 13.6-20.5 16.5-30.7 20.2-47.5 4.2-18.9 4.2-38.8 2.1-58-1.3-11.8-4.8-23.3-8.9-34.4-6.7-18.1-9.8-25.7-25.4-51.9-5.9-10.1-11-18.4-11.2-18.7-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2zm-109 24.6c-0.3 0-0.7 0.7-1.1 1.5-3.7 8.4-5.8 16.7-7.8 25.3-2.3 9.8-3.6 19.9-4.9 30-0.9 7.1-0.8 5.3-1.9 21.4-0.7 10.4-0.6 14.4 0.6 26 0.9 8.9 1.5 11.7 2.9 17.4 1.6 6.5 3.2 12.9 6.5 19 4.5 8.7 11.7 16.9 19.9 22.6 1.8 1.3 3.7 2.3 4.3 2.3 1.3 0 1.6-0.8 0.9-2.7-0.5-1-0.8-1.9-1.2-2.8-2.7-7.8-4.6-15.8-6.6-23.7-1.6-6.4-2.9-12.8-4.2-19.2-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.2-3.2-18.3-1-7.1-2-14.1-2.5-21.2-0.8-12.3-1.3-27.1-1.5-40.4-0.1-11.6 0-22.1 0.5-28.8 0.4-5.9 0.2-8.2-0.8-8.2zm83 0c-1 0-1.2 2.3-0.8 8.2 0.5 6.8 0.6 17.3 0.5 28.8-0.2 13.3-0.7 28.1-1.5 40.4-0.5 7.1-1.4 14.2-2.5 21.2-0.9 6.1-2 12.2-3.2 18.3-1.3 6.4-2.6 12.8-4.2 19.2-2 8-3.9 16-6.6 23.7-0.3 1-0.7 1.8-1.2 2.8-0.7 1.8-0.4 2.7 0.9 2.7 0.5 0 2.5-1 4.3-2.3 8.3-5.8 15.5-14 19.9-22.6 3.3-6.1 4.9-12.5 6.5-19 1.4-5.7 2-8.5 2.9-17.4 1.2-11.6 1.3-15.6 0.6-26-1.1-16.1-1-14.3-1.9-21.4-1.3-10-2.5-20.1-4.9-30-2-8.6-4.1-16.9-7.8-25.3-0.3-0.8-0.8-1.5-1.1-1.5zm-44.1 5.9c-13.8 0-14.7 0.1-15.2 0.9-0.7 1 0.2 15.1 0.5 22.7 0.3 8 0.9 16.1 1.4 24.1 0.6 8.7 1.2 17.3 2.2 26 0.8 7.4 1.4 14.8 3.1 22 1.5 6.7 3.8 13.2 6.3 19.6 1.2 3.1 3.3 8.3 4.3 9.1 1-0.9 3.1-6 4.3-9.1 2.5-6.4 4.8-12.9 6.3-19.6 1.7-7.2 2.3-14.6 3.1-22 1-8.6 1.5-17.3 2.2-26 0.6-8 1.1-16.1 1.4-24.1 0.3-7.6 1.2-21.7 0.5-22.7-0.5-0.8-1.4-0.8-15.2-0.9-1.3 0.1-2 0.1-2.6 0.1-0.7 0-1.3 0-2.6-0.1z">
 
 </path>
    </g>
  
</svg> 

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Здарова Саша ! А можно ли сделать что бы прорисовка была сплошной линией?

Comment: @MaximLensky можно, но для этого надо полностью перерисовать рисунок, а я не художник к сожалению ((( Дело в том, обрати внимание внутри много подпутей, которые начинаются с маленькой `m` Вот они и рисуются поэтому одновременно.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Super....